# Problems installing MathTime Professional 2 font on TexLive

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive, mtpro

**June 2014 update**: on the basis of this page and [the question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87300/help-using-mathtime-pro-2-fonts-in-ubuntu-linux-with-tex-live) I have written an installer for the MathTime fonts that should work with Unix systems running TeX Live. [The installer page is on my website](http://cims.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/). My script has been successfully tested on Ubuntu 14.04 w/ TeX Live 2013, and a two year old MacBook Air running OS X w/ TeX Live 2012.

---

Recently I've been trying to install the [MathTime Professional 2 font](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) (free Lite version). I'm using TeX Live on Ubuntu 12.04.

I downloaded the files and copied them over to the folder `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/`. (The instructions suggested putting them in `/usr/share/texmf/`, but this didn't work for me.) After umpteen runs of `texhash`, `updmap` and `updmap-sys`, the `pdflatex` command can now find `mtpro2.map`. However now when I run `pdflatex` on a simple file

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}    % set Helvetica as the sans-serif font
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}      % set Times as the default text font
\usepackage{amsmath}        
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
This is a test secton
$a$
\end{document}
```

I get the following error

```
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd))
(./LaTeX Article MTPro2Lite.aux) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdft
ex.map}] (./LaTeX Article MTPro2Lite.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 mt2mit
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for mt2mit.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file mt2mit): Font mt2mit at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I've been Googling for about an hour trying to a find a solution, but I've found nothing. Does anyone have any advice on how I might proceed?

I'm a complete n00b when it comes to installing extras for LaTeX; sorry if this question is inappropriate.

**Edit**: running `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map mtpro2.map` outputs:

```
updmap: This is updmap, version $Id: updmap 14402 2009-07-23 17:09:15Z karl $
updmap: using transcript file `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.log'
updmap: initial config file is `/var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg'
```

Comment: The error means that the `updmap-sys` run has not made what it should. You should *not* run `updmap`; first try removing the `/home/james/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` file (the one created by `updmap`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've deleted the .texmf-var directory but I'm still getting the same error. The file mt2mit.tfm is in the proper place in the texmf directory, and more runs of updmap-sys and texhash haven't done anything.

Comment: Did you run `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map mtpro2.map`?

Comment: Yes. Was just about to say: should I be worried that the command  the `updmap-sys --enable` command only outputs 3 lines? It doesn't, for instance, run the `updmap-sys` command afterwards to refresh all the files. On the other hand, when I run `updmap-sys --disable` it subsequently executes `updmap-sys`.

Comment: Please, modify the reported lines in the log file that you get now, after having removed the improper `pdftex.map` file.

Comment: @egreg: updated now.

Comment: You have a mixed installation: something refers to `texmf`, something to `texmf-texlive`. It's quite hard to debug this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6047/discussion-between-egreg-and-james-fennell)

Comment: Does the installer take care also of the Lite version?

Comment: @egreg - the installer was designed using the Lite version (I don't have the complete fonts.) I was in contact with the creator of the fonts, who sent me a list of the files contained in the complete version; from looking at that it seems unlikely that the installer wouldn't also work for the complete set.

Comment: Good to know. `:-)` Maybe you can clarify it on your Web page.

Comment: @egreg done! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that some problems have accumulated. As a last resort I'd try editing by hand the `updmap.cfg` file: with your favorite editor open the file, for instance with

```
sudo vim $(kpsewhich updmap.cfg)
```

and add at the end the line

```
Map mtpro2.map
```

Then run

```
sudo updmap-sys
```

and the system should be able to find the fonts.

Comment: This worked! @egreg was kind enough to offer his time on chat to fix the problem (we were on chat for nearly an hour). I am very, very grateful. Thank you egreg!

Comment: @JamesFennell Happy to have been able to help.