# Help using MathTime Pro 2 fonts in Ubuntu Linux with tex-live

Tags: fonts, texlive, ubuntu, mtpro

I installed the MTPro2 fonts in Ubuntu 12.04 by extracting the MTPro2
ZIP file into a directory called "mathtime" and then doing the
following:

```
sudo mv mathtime/* /usr/local/share/texmf/
cd /usr/local/share/texmf/
sudo texhash
sudo updmap --disable mt-belleek.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap --disable belleek.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap --disable mt-yy.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap --disable mt-plus.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap --enable Map mtpro2.map
sudo chmod -R a+r+x /usr/local/share/texmf/
```

However, when trying to compile a LaTeX document that uses the MTPro2
fonts, I get the following:

```
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./mtpro2.sty
kpathsea: Running mktextfm mt2exa
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1;
nonstopmode; input mt2exa
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf mt2exa
! I can't find file `mt2exa'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input mt2exa
```

There are more messages before and after the portion shown immediately above, but I think this is the most relevant portion.

Everything used to work fine under Ubuntu 11.10, but I recently
installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a new machine, and now I can't get the
MTPro2 fonts to work. Help! :)

**[Below is a full directory-hierarchical list of the contents of the MTPro2 ZIP file.]**

```
.
├── EULA.txt
├── templates
│   ├── LaTeX Article MTPro2Lite.tex
│   ├── LaTeX Article MTPro2.tex
│   ├── MTPro2 LaTeX test.tex
│   └── Plain MTPro2.tex
└── texmf
    ├── doc
    │   └── fonts
    │       └── mtpro2
    │           ├── EULA.txt
    │           ├── guide2.pdf
    │           ├── mtpro2.pdf
    │           ├── Test_latex.pdf
    │           └── Test_latex.tex
    ├── dvips
    │   └── mtpro2
    │       └── mtpro2.map
    ├── fonts
    │   ├── map
    │   │   └── dvips
    │   │       └── mtpro2
    │   │           └── mtpro2.map
    │   ├── tfm
    │   │   └── pctex
    │   │       └── mtpro2
    │   │           ├── mt2bbdf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bbds.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bbdt.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bbf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bbif.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bbis.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bbit.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bbs.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bbt.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bexa.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bmff.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bmfs.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bmft.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bmif.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bmis.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bmit.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bmsf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bmss.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bmst.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bsyaf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bsyas.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bsyat.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bsyf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bsys.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2bsyt.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2exa.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2exe.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2exf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2exg.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hbif.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hbis.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hbit.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hexa.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hrbdf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hrbds.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hrbdt.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hrbf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hrbs.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hrbt.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hsyaf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hsyas.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hsyat.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hsyf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hsys.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2hsyt.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mbf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mbs.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mbt.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mcf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mcs.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mct.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mff.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mfs.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mft.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mif.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mis.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mit.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2msf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mss.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2mst.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2syaf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2syas.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2syat.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2syf.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2sys.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2syt.tfm
    │   │           ├── mt2xl.tfm
    │   │           └── mt2xxxl.tfm
    │   └── type1
    │       └── pctex
    │           └── mtpro2
    │               ├── mt2bbdf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bbdf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bbds.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bbds.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bbdt.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bbdt.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bbf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bbf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bbif.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bbif.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bbis.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bbis.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bbit.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bbit.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bbs.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bbs.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bbt.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bbt.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bexa.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bexa.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bmff.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bmff.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bmfs.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bmfs.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bmft.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bmft.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bmif.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bmif.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bmis.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bmis.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bmit.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bmit.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bmsf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bmsf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bmss.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bmss.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bmst.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bmst.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bsyaf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bsyaf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bsyas.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bsyas.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bsyat.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bsyat.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bsyf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bsyf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bsys.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bsys.pfm
    │               ├── mt2bsyt.pfb
    │               ├── mt2bsyt.pfm
    │               ├── mt2exa.pfb
    │               ├── mt2exa.pfm
    │               ├── mt2exe.pfb
    │               ├── mt2exe.pfm
    │               ├── mt2exf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2exf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2exg.pfb
    │               ├── mt2exg.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hbif.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hbif.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hbis.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hbis.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hbit.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hbit.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hexa.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hexa.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hrbdf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hrbdf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hrbds.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hrbds.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hrbdt.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hrbdt.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hrbf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hrbf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hrbs.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hrbs.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hrbt.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hrbt.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hsyaf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hsyaf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hsyas.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hsyas.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hsyat.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hsyat.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hsyf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hsyf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hsys.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hsys.pfm
    │               ├── mt2hsyt.pfb
    │               ├── mt2hsyt.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mbf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mbf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mbs.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mbs.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mbt.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mbt.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mcf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mcf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mcs.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mcs.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mct.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mct.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mff.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mff.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mfs.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mfs.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mft.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mft.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mif.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mif.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mis.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mis.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mit.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mit.pfm
    │               ├── mt2msf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2msf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mss.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mss.pfm
    │               ├── mt2mst.pfb
    │               ├── mt2mst.pfm
    │               ├── mt2syaf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2syaf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2syas.pfb
    │               ├── mt2syas.pfm
    │               ├── mt2syat.pfb
    │               ├── mt2syat.pfm
    │               ├── mt2syf.pfb
    │               ├── mt2syf.pfm
    │               ├── mt2sys.pfb
    │               ├── mt2sys.pfm
    │               ├── mt2syt.pfb
    │               ├── mt2syt.pfm
    │               ├── mt2xl.pfb
    │               ├── mt2xl.pfm
    │               ├── mt2xxxl.pfb
    │               └── mt2xxxl.pfm
    ├── source
    │   └── latex
    │       └── mtpro2
    │           ├── mtpro2.dtx
    │           └── mtpro2.ins
    ├── tex
    │   ├── latex
    │   │   └── mtpro2
    │   │       ├── mtpro2.sty
    │   │       ├── omslbm.fd
    │   │       ├── umt2bb.fd
    │   │       ├── umt2hrb.fd
    │   │       ├── umt2mf.fd
    │   │       └── umt2ms.fd
    │   └── plain
    │       └── mtpro2
    │           └── mtp2.tex
    └── tpm
        └── package
            └── mtp2fonts.tpm

27 directories, 226 files
```

Comment: Please try again with `updmap-sys` instead of `updmap`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder -- it seems worse than that: latex can't even find the .tfm.  surely there are instructions that came with mtpro2?  (it comes from a respectable seller, after all...)  if those instructions have gone away, and can't be found via the [pctex web site](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html), pctex probably have a help desk you can mail to.

Comment: Can you show the structure below the `mathtime` directory when you unzip the archive? You should also remove the `pdftex.map` created by using `updmap` instead of the correct `updmap-sys`

Comment: @wasteofspace: Because with `sudo updmap` he either creates a map for the root user or one only readable by root. He should AFAIK _either_ use `updmap` _or_ `sudo updmap-sys`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I removed my ~/.texmf* directories and then repeated the installation process without sudo.  The same error occurs though. Any other ideas?

Comment: @wasteofspace there aren't instructions for installing on Linux with TeX Live.  However, I followed the same installation procedure I described above when I was using my other computer with an older version of Ubuntu installed.  It worked perfectly there.

Comment: @egreg I added the structure to the original post above.  Also, I deleted the file `/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` that has a timestamp indicating it was created yesterday (and thus is probably the erroneous one I created yesterday).

Comment: @synaptik It seems good. But I'm concerned with the initial `mv` command that seems wrong. In any case you should use `sudo updmap-sys` for rebuilding the map files.

Comment: @egreg OK, I did that, but the problem remains.  Should I totally purge tex-live from my system and reinstall it, and then use a different installation procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the original problem, and then another problem that arose after fixing the original problem.  Now it works perfectly.  Let me explain...

As you can see from the full directory-hierarchical list of the contents of the MTPro2 ZIP file in the original post, the ZIP file contains a directory named `texmf`. The original problem was due to the fact that I moved the `texmf` directory *itself* into the directory `/usr/local/share/texmf/`, whereas I should have moved the *contents* of this directory into `/usr/local/share/texmf`. Thus, the directory and file set that was supposed to be located in `/usr/local/share/texmf/` was actually located in `/usr/local/share/texmf/texmf`.

So, I removed all my local settings by issuing the command (with sudo because I may have accidentally created some files as root previously):

`sudo rm -rf ~/.texmf-*`

I next removed the MTPro2 files from the *incorrect* location using the command:

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/texmf/texmf`

Then I moved the MTPro2 files to the correct location using the command:

`sudo cp -r ~/ZIP_FILE_CONTENTS/texmf/* /usr/local/share/texmf/`

Next, I issued the **correct commands** to update my system:

```
sudo texhash
sudo updmap-sys --disable mt-belleek.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap-sys --disable belleek.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap-sys --disable mt-yy.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap-sys --disable mt-plus.map --nomkmap
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map mtpro2.map
sudo chmod -R a+r+x /usr/local/share/texmf/
```

So, now that I had (or thought I had) correctly installed MTPro2, I attempted to build a sample document using the MTPro2 fonts.  The original error message was gone (yay!), but a different message appeared:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 4+0/600 --dpi 2400 mt2exf
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for mt2exf.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file mt2exf): Font mt2exf at 2400 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

But the solution to this new problem was fixed easily by the solution described in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75679/problems-installing-mathtime-professional-2-font-on-texlive).  Namely, I manually appended to the file `$(kpsewhich updmap.cfg)` a line containing the text `Map mtpro2.map`, and then re-ran `sudo updmap-sys`.

Comment: Also, see:  https://groups.google.com/group/latexusersgroup/browse_thread/thread/19fbb4cb9f3af6a5

Comment: Excellent! I'm the author of the tex.se question you link to at the end, but I had to install Mathtime again recently and these instructions worked completely painlessly. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: There is now an installer for the MTPro2 fonts for TeX Live systems on Unix: http://cims.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/ Hope it works for you! I wrote the installer based on the instructions on this page, and have successfully tested it on Ubuntu 14.04 w/ TeX Live 2013, and a two year old Mac running OS X and TeX Live 2012. @egreg