# Problem installing subcaption package on texlive

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu, subcaption

I'm trying to install the subcaption package on TexLive installed on Ubuntu 11.10.  When trying to build subcaption.sty, I found that I needed to first download or build several dependencies:

```
diagbox.sty
epic.sty
footmisc.sty
overpic.sty
pict2e.sty
```

After putting these files in the same directory as subcaption.dtx, I try to build subcaption.sty and here is the result:

```
$ latex subcaption.dtx 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./subcaption.dtx
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ltxdoc.cls
Document Class: ltxdoc 2007/11/11 v2.0u Standard LaTeX documentation class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/doc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty) (./footmisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def))) (./overpic.sty
Package: overpic v0.53 <2010/09/13> (RN)
(./epic.sty
Enhancements to Picture Environment. Version 1.2 - Released June 1, 1986
)
overpic: relative positioning in percent
) (./pict2e.sty (./p2e-dvips.def)) (./diagbox.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/hypdoc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/hycolor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/xcolor-patch.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty))
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty))
Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ltxmisc/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/bitset.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/bigintcalc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty))
*hyperref using default driver hdvips*
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def

Package hyperref Warning: You have enabled option `breaklinks'.
(hyperref)                But driver `hdvips.def' does not suppport this.
(hyperref)                Expect trouble with the link areas of broken links.

)) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/thumbpdf/thumbpdf.sty

Package thumbpdf Warning: Missing driver name.

)) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty

! Package subcaption Error: `caption' package not loaded
(subcaption)                (which is needed by this package)

See the subcaption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.38   \endinput}{}

?
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I fix this?

(I'm a novice... I don't know what dtx, ins, or sty files are.  All I know is that I can usually run `latex file.ins` to produce `file.sty` and then put `file.sty` in an appropriate directory and use that package.)

**[After installing the latest version of TexLive, I had problems... see link below]**

[Problems with TexLive 2012 on Ubuntu after network installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96965/problems-with-texlive-2012-on-ubuntu-after-network-installation)

Comment: Have a look at [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) you shouldn't need to do any 'manual' installation for `subcaption`

Comment: The `subcaption` package needs `caption` so you have to install also that one. But trying to update a very old distribution like yours (more than three years) is quite hopeless. Do as cmhughes recommends, you won't regret it.

Comment: Which answer at the page that cmhughes links to should I follow?

Comment: @synaptik I would recommend removing your old distribution completely as in [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95483) and then follow the instructions in the first answer to [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Comment: @cmhughes OK, I have installed via the suggested directions.  Now, I need to reinstall my MathTime Pro 2 fonts.  Should I simply install them as described in the answer to [Problems installing MathTime Professional 2 font on TexLive](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87300/help-using-mathtime-pro-2-fonts-in-ubuntu-linux-with-tex-live)? Or is there a different way to install them now that I'm using the latest version of TexLive?

Comment: @synaptik I don't know about that...

Comment: Why don't you just download http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/caption.tds.zip ? There is no need to build the sty files (or documentation) by yourself. (BTW: `latex subcaption.dtx` will not build `subcaption.sty` but `subcaption.pdf` instead. `latex caption.ins` will build `subcaption.sty`)

Comment: Instead of installing TeX packages by yourself, please either install TeX and its packages from your distribution or install vanilla TeXLive and use it's package manager.

Comment: `subcaption` is installed by default in my ubuntu system.  are you sure it isn't in yours? -- `kpsewhich subcaption.sty` will tell you (no output if it's not installed)

Comment: @wasteofspace on my other Ubuntu system (which has the texlive installed via apt), subcaption.sty does appear to be installed.  Here is the error though: `! Package subcaption Error: `caption' package not loaded (subcaption) (which is needed by this package)`

Comment: @synaptik The only mistake you have done is trying to compile the actual version of the `subcaption` package documentation with only having an old version installed. (And as already mentioned there is usually absolutely no need to compile the documentation by yourself.)

Answer (score 4):

`latex subcaption.dtx` will *not* build `subcaption.sty` but the documentation `subcaption.dvi` resp. `subcaption.pdf` instead. The `subcaption` package itself does *not* have dependencies to `diagbox.sty`, `epic.sty`, `footmisc.sty`, `overpic.sty`, or `pict2e.sty`, you only need them to build the documentation for yourself. (This step is not necessary since the documentation already comes pre-build as `subcaption.pdf`.)

You are getting the error message "caption package not loaded" when building the `subcaption` package documentation for yourself since building the documentation requires the actual version of the `subcaption` package installed. So you need to update the `caption` package bundle (which includes `subcaption.sty`) first.

`latex caption.ins` or `tex caption.ins` will build the required package files, i.e. `caption.sty`, ..., and `subcaption.sty`. But the easiest way to get a LaTeX package from CTAN is to look for a TDS structured archive first, they are located at

http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/

As you see there is a caption.tds.zip, so getting this file, unzipping it, and putting its contents to the right location is all you need to do to install/update the whole `caption` package bundle including sty files and docs.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. How can I find out what the *right location* is?

Comment: @synaptik Unpack the zip file within a texmf directory of your choice, e.g. `$HOME/texmf`. See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files

Comment: @synaptik ...and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system