# Does TeXLive2013 need any special install instructions?

Tags: installing, texlive

When I installed TeXLive2012 on Linux some time ago, I had to follow [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu).  For the new release, as of yesterday, will I need to mimic the procedure from 2012 or can it be done in an easier fashion this time?  Or does it have to be installed in an entirely different way?

**Edit 2:**

After uninstalling:

```
Setting up tex-common (3.15) ...
Directory /etc/texmf/ not writeable. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Edit 3:**

Now, whenever I run commands in the terminal, I receive this:

```
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
Setting up tex-common (3.15) ...
Directory /etc/texmf/ not writeable. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up tex-common (3.15) ...
Directory /etc/texmf/ not writeable. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
```

This occurred when I ran `sudo aptitude update` and then running `upgrade`.  I followed everything from cmhughes link on removing TeXLive.

Comment: Nope- I just installed it today, and it worked fine. I removed TL 2012 as detailed in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437), but some folks choose to keep two distributions in parallel

Comment: Yes indeed- download and unzip the `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`, then run `sudo ./install`. Once installed, update the paths, and you're set :)

Comment: do `tlmgr uninstall` and then see [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95483)

Comment: Actually the installation instructions can be improved. But this is the Linux world, and those who write instructions assume many things. For example, I had to install TK and perl-tk before, else the gui will not come up (it did not say to do that) Also, it did not say to use `sudo` or not to use `sudo` on the command. I had to guess to use `sudo`

Comment: @Nasser I used sudo for everything and in the link in the op it mentions perl to use the manager.  But I still would like to know how to fix the issue I am having at present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you follow [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu) and receive the problem I have had, you need to do this:

```
sudo apt-get remove tex-common --purge
```

This will remove whatever hidden dependency that remains and then tries to reinstall later if you run and `apt-get upgrade` or `aptitude upgrade`.

Then I followed: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

Comment: I think this stuff you had left over was from the repositories....

Comment: @cmhughes possibly.  It should have been mentioned in the post on how to remove from Ubuntu though but it wasn't.

Comment: Is this thread/Issue related to your Q [sudo apt-get purge texlive* tex-common*](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96977/15717)

Comment: @texenthusiast that wasn't my question.  I have never seen it until you pointed it out but that line is key when uninstalling TeXLive from Ubuntu.