# Troubles with TeX Live 2009 and 2013

Tags: installing, texlive, debugging

Well, before Christmas I was updating some software in my Ubuntu 12.04 installation, where I have happily installed TeX Live 2013 since last summer (I did it from an ISO image downloaded from the CTAN). I found yesterday in the software center a interesting program called [QTikZ](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qtikz/) and I want to try it. But it crashed and produced an [error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/1222892). The attempt of installation also installed an old TeX Live version from 2009 that now crashes every time I update, uninstall, or install something. So I uninstalled QTikZ and some software, longtime unused, but the error remains.

I remember three posts about install TeX Live 2013 and what to do before:

[Post 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120120/does-texlive2013-need-any-special-install-instructions), 
[Post 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution), 
[Post 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu)

So my question is what to do for uninstall TeX Live 2009 without break or loose TeX Live 2013?

Merry Christmas for everybody and in advance thanks you all.

Comment: Distributions on a UNIX system live in `/usr/local/texlive/<year>/`, so you should be able to have multiple distributions on the same machine without any conflict. Then, it's just a matter of making sure that the file path of the distribution you want to use at any given time is in your `PATH`.

Comment: Well actually my trouble is not for compile wiht LaTeX is for install and update all my software, always Ubuntu remembers me the conflict with TeXLive 2009.

Comment: You cannot update old versions of TeXLive. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/32888

Comment: Well I don't want to update an old version, I simply want to remove the 2009 version without break the 2013 one. But I don't know how to remove it safely.

Comment: Can you please say how you installed (1) TeX Live 2009, (2) TeX Live 2013 and (3) any other installation of TeX you currently have installed? You said you wanted to fix the problems with 2009 but now you say you want to uninstall it altogether - please clarify. Moreover please explain the nature of the problem you are experiencing. We do not (hopefully) have access to your machine so we have to rely on you to *describe* the problem.

Comment: Thanks @cfr I corrected few details and I added information for reply your questions. (1) I installed TeXLive2009 accidentally yesterday trying to install QTikz. (2) TeXLive 2013 was installed the last summer from an DVD donwloaded from the CTAN. And (3) I have no other TeXLive installation.