# Packages to install once for all

Tags: packages, texlive

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04.

Then, I have manually installed `tex-common`, `texlive-base` and `texlive-latex-recommended`.

And I realize that some packages do not exist anymore. For instance, `multirow`, `paralist`, `stmaryrd`, `subfigure`, etc.

Could anyone tell me what I should install to have these packages the once for all?

Comment: This is a Debian question as it depends on Debian's packaging. It is arguably easier to install and maintain TeX Live using upstream's installer. There is a question here covering the process for installing vanilla TL on Debian/Ubuntu which I recommend checking out.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/sid/texlive-latex-extra

Comment: Well Ubuntu is quite different from Debian, I understand this trouble because I had the same trouble before. My suggestion is to install TeXLive 2014 instead of the versions from the ubuntu/debian repositories that are now not from 2009 but from 2012.

Comment: @Aradnix Does Ubuntu's packaging of TL now differ from Debian's? I didn't know that. In that case, though, it is an Ubuntu question as it depends on Ubuntu's packaging. But it is still easier to install vanilla TL from upstream IMHO.

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?lq=1) is the question I referred to.

Comment: @cfr Well actually I don't know where gets ubuntu the TeXLive packages from, ie from which Debian repository, probably from the stable branch, in testing I think it is already version 2014, but since Ubuntu 13.04 they updated from TxLive 2009 to TexLive 2012 and I think the packages they use are still from that year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well:

I used Ubuntu a long time ago, I used to install the LTS versions and there I used to install TeXlive full until I found errors in some packages and I noticed my versions installed were older than the versions contained in the CTAN.

As I use to prove a lot of packages and I use LaTeX for a wide variety of documents I decided to install TeXLive directly from the CTAN instead of the local repositories of the distro since 2013 (and now 2018).

Before continue, I think is a good idea to read these previous questions related:

- [How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95483/how-to-remove-everything-related-to-tex-live-for-fresh-install-on-ubuntu)
- [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)
- [Does TeXLive2013 need any special install instructions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120120/does-texlive2013-need-any-special-install-instructions)

Once you read it and understood how to uninstall all the previous packages for avoiding troubles, you can download the iso file with the TeXLive 2014 compilation from here `http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2018.iso` or if you prefer it, there is a [script](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texlive/eitl) that you can use for installing it too.

In the case of the iso image, be sure you have installed the `perl-tk` library before because otherwise, you won't be able to run the GUI of the installer.

Good luck.

Comment: I fully agree with this answer. I used the ubuntu packages for many years but was often frustrated by the old package versions and the lack of control over package installations. Inversting some time in understanding and installing texlive really worth it!!

Comment: Note that `perl-tk` is only required for the GUI installer. The standard installer does not require it. (I've never used the GUI version on Linux.) Also, unless you have a dodgy connection, the net-installer is arguably preferable. That way you get an updated installation immediately. (This is the standard installation method for Linux. The `.iso` is an alternative for people who need to burn DVDs etc.)