# Installing MathTimes Pro 2 Ubuntu GNU/Linux

Tags: mtpro

(Not really a duplicate, got some errors that wasn't in the previous guide)
[Help using MathTime Pro 2 fonts in Ubuntu Linux with tex-live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87300/help-using-mathtime-pro-2-fonts-in-ubuntu-linux-with-tex-live)

What I have done:
1. Extracted the contents of the mpt2fonts.zip.tpm into a folder called mathtime.

2. Moved the contents of mathime into /usr/local/share/texmf, using 
   sudo mv mathime/* /usr/local/share/texmf
3. Then did the following 
   sudo texhash
   sudo updmap-sys --disable mt-belleek.map --nomkmap
   sudo updmap-sys --disable belleek.map --nomkmap
   sudo updmap-sys --disable mt-yy.map --nomkmap
   sudo updmap-sys --disable mt-plus.map --nomkmap
   sudo updmap-sys --enable Map mtpro2.map
   sudo chmod -R a+r+x /usr/local/share/texmf/
4. I then verified that $(kpsewhich updmap.cfg) contained the line Map mtpro2.map, which it did.

However, I get the error

! LaTeX Error: File `mtpro2.sty' not found.Type X to quit or  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop. \usepackage

and

!==> Fatal Error (...) No PDf produced

How do I proceed?
Thanks in advance

EDIT> since i wrote this up, I have also ran `mktexlsr`, which did not help

Comment: If mtpro2.sty isn't found then it either doesn't exist, or is in the wrong folder, or you didn't update the file name database (run mktexlsr).

Comment: How can I check if it doesn't exist or is in the wrong folder? I ran mktexlsr, it didn't help.

Comment: Search for it and tell us in which folder it is.

Comment: You didn't say you ran `mktexlsr` in your description.

Comment: @cfr, I didn't say it since I didn't know it. I tried it after Ulrike Fischer said it.

Comment: What does `kpsewhich mtpro2.sty` give? Where did you install this file?