# Troubles installing MathTime Pro 2 (MacTex)

Tags: fonts, installing, mactex, mtpro

I follow the directions here:

```
$sudo texhash
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories:       /opt/local/etc/texmf.
texhash: Done.
```

But I can fix this by doing

```
$sudo /usr/texbin/texhash/
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-config/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

Then I do `updmap-sys --enable Map=mtpro2.map`:

```
$sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=mtpro2.map 
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /opt/local/etc/texmf.
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /opt/local/etc/texmf.
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /opt/local/etc/texmf.
updmap: Cannot find TEXMFROOT, aborting!
```

I know for sure that `texmf.cnf` is not in the specified directory since that is from an old installation (not MacTeX). The correct location is `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf.cnf` but I have no idea how to get these commands to recognize this.

And fyi, `which kpathsea` returns nothing.

Comment: Perhaps this does help: [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88423) and especially [Problems installing MathTime Professional 2 font on TexLive](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75679).

Comment: How did you install TeX exactly? I ask because MacTeX used to install by default under `/usr/local`. I thought perhaps it had changed to `/opt` but https://www.tug.org/mactex//What_Is_Installed.pdf suggests that it still installs into `/usr/local`. Did you customise your installation directory? Install TeX through some other means? Or?

Comment: @cfr I installed for the first time while installing TeXShop, but then I later installed Kile using macports. You're right that if I do `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` I get `/opt/local/share/texmf-local`

Comment: So you probably have two installations of TeX. This is not really a good idea unless you are sure you know what you are doing. I'm guessing that's not the case because you say you are using MacTeX when you clearly are not. I would recommend uninstalling the `macports` one, making sure you have the latest MacTeX and then trying again. I am not sure how `macports` works at this point so I'm not sure what to suggest about `Kile` but MacTeX is likely to be more straightforward and better maintained than the `macports` version. (Just because it is specialist and direct from the source, as it were.)

Comment: @cfr yeah, I haven't been using `Kile` much recently so I went and uninstalled the texlive via `macports` or at least I think I did. But the problem now is that after re-installing MacTeX, if I do `sudo texhash` I get warning: `kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /opt/local/etc/texmf`. I actually can't find that file anywhere in my system. But TeXShop is working without issues as far as I can tell

Comment: Actually, I can find the `texmf.cnf` file fine but I don't know how to tell `texhash` to look for it in a different location...

Comment: What does `which kpathsea` give? If it is in `/opt`, you didn't get everything when you uninstalled.

Comment: @cfr `which kpathsea` is blank

Comment: Okay, so if I do `sudo /usr/texbin/texhash` then `texhash` works now. But if I try to enable the map I still get errors. See original post for edit

Comment: Maybe your `PATH` is wrong? What does `echo $PATH` give? Or, even, `sudo echo $PATH`? Is `/usr/texbin` included? Can you run `sudo /usr/texbin/updmap-sys...` successfully?