# Problem using locally installed font

Tags: fonts, installing

I installed a font locally under $HOME/texmf, and after running `texhash` everything seems to be in place:

```
> kpsewhich mtpro2.map
/home/mafp/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/mtpro2/mtpro2.map
> kpsewhich mt2exe.tfm
/home/mafp/texmf/fonts/tfm/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exe.tfm
> kpsewhich mt2exe.pfb
/home/mafp/texmf/fonts/type1/pctex/mtpro2/mt2exe.pfb
```

Then I ran

```
> updmap --enable Map=mtpro2.map
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

which sounds fishy, I guess it should use a updmap.cfg under TEXMFHOME. And indeed, translating a simple test file using the font gives

```
> pdflatex mtpro2test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mtpro2bug.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/home/mafp/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/home/mafp/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/home/mafp/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/home/mafp/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/home/mafp/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/home/mafp/texmf/tex/latex/mtpro2/mtpro2.sty) (./mtpro2test.aux) [1{/usr/share/
texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./mtpro2test.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 2+0/600 --dpi 1200 mt2exe
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for mt2exe.
mktexpk: perhaps mt2exe is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file mt2exe): Font mt2exe at 1200 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: do you need to run `updmap` with superuser privileges and/or should you be running `updmap-sys` (again via `sudo`)? A separate comment: Lots of other files (e.g., amsmath.sty and its subordinated style files) also seem to live in `/home/mafp/texmf/tex/latex/...` rather than in the more common location `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/...` -- do you install most packages under `$HOME/texmf`?

Comment: *Never* install fonts in `TEXMFHOME` unless you really don't have superuser privileges. Use `TEXMFLOCAL` and `sudo updmap-sys`. If you do this way, remember to remove the `pdftex.map` file created with `updmap`

Comment: @egreg OK, I will try that. Is this a technical limitation of `updmap`, or is there a good reason behind that?

Comment: @mafp When you run `tlmgr` or, in general, update the TeX distribution and some new font is installed (or an old one is modified), `updmap-sys` is called. It won't touch your `pdftex.map` file generated with `updmap`, so you have to run it periodically.

Comment: Just as reference: See also [Problems installing MathTime Professional 2 font on TexLive](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75679)

Comment: @egreg Can you write an answer? Currently, the only answer gives what seems to me to be terrible advice. (Of course, if I'm wrong about that, no doubt somebody will be good enough to tell me so.)

Comment: @cfr Done, please add your comments, if any.

Answer (score 7):

Installing fonts in `TEXMFHOME` should be the last resort only for somebody who has no super user privilege or, more precisely, no write access to `TEXMFLOCAL`.

The environment variable `TEXMFLOCAL` points to

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

on “vanilla” TeX Live installations, to

```
/usr/local/share/texmf
```

on TeX Live/Debian. I have no idea what it points to with SuSE Linux, but it's unimportant, because the shell command

```
kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL
```

will always give the right answer.

From the 2013 release, TeX Live uses a slightly different mechanism for building `pdftex.map` with `updmap` or `updmap-sys`. Each of the three trees `TEXMFMAIN`, `TEXMFLOCAL` and `TEXMFHOME` can have a `updmap.cfg` file under the subdirectory `web2c` and the recommended procedure is to add map files to the relevant `updmap.cfg` file; so, instead of `updmap(-sys) --enable Map=mtpro2.map` one should *append* the line

```
Map mtpro2.map
```

to the chosen `updmap.cfg` file and then run either `updmap` or `updmap-sys` *without* arguments.

So, for a user's only addition, the line should be appended to

```
$(kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME)/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

(I assume Bash shell), while for the better method (if one has write access to `TEXMFLOCAL`), the line should be appended to

```
$(kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

Then run `updmap` in the first case, `sudo updmap-sys` in the second case (or just `updmap-sys` from a superuser shell, depending on your OS idiosyncrasies).

Of course, all the font related files will have been installed using the appropriate tree. ***NEVER*** use `TEXMFDIST` for installing fonts not included in TeX Live.

Why is it better to use `TEXMFLOCAL` whenever possible? Because when `tlmgr` (vanilla TeX Live) or the OS specific package manager do an update to TeX Live which involves font packages, they will run `updmap-sys` that of course won't use the `updmap.cfg` file in `TEXMFHOME` (which would only refer to the one specific for the `root` user).

Thus, anybody who has run `updmap`, will have their `pdftex.map` file *unupdated*, so `updmap` should be manually run periodically, in order to reflect possible changes to the main, distribution managed, `updmap.cfg` file. Always using `updmap-sys` (with additional fonts in `TEXMFLOCAL`) avoids the problem. Note that `TEXMFLOCAL` is never touched by updates, and will be used as is by future releases of TeX Live.

There is always the risk of installing in `TEXMFLOCAL` something that later finds its place in the main distribution (it happened to me with the STIX fonts, for instance).

Anyway, my advice is to use only the vanilla TeX Live, even on Debian, Fedora, SuSE or whatnot systems.

Comment: (+1) Is the advantage of appending the line to the `.cfg` file that it will be automatically picked up when updating to a new version of TeX Live? I've mostly used the argument to `updmap-sys` and the `getnonfreefonts-sys` script must also do it that way. The only disadvantage I can see is that these changes won't be transferred when I get TL 2015. Do you have a reference for the new recommendation? The manual pages for `updmap.cfg` and `updmap-sys` don't seem to mention it, for example.

Comment: @cfr Look for `updmap.cfg` in `texdoc tlmgr`

Comment: Thanks. It isn't clear to me that that is supposed to mean that `updmap-sys --enable Map=` shouldn't be used, though. Isn't the point that the local `updmap.cfg` should be used rather than `updmap-local.cfg`?

Comment: If you are correct then the instructions in `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFDIST)/web2c/updmap-hdr.cfg` are incorrect.

Comment: @cfr Yes; I guess they didn't update it. See `updmap --help`

Comment: If you are right, then it is a real mess because `updmap-sys` really should write changes to the appropriate `updmap.cfg` file i.e in the local tree if the maps are in the local tree. Anyway, I just deleted my TEXMFCONFIG and added everything to the local `updmap.cfg`. Because it seems that the version in TEXMFCONFIG ought not generally be used. At least, it ought not be used for adding map files.

Comment: Explanation of ***why*** you should follow this advice can be found in my [question/answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i) on this.

Answer (score 1):

Just type in terminal

```
sudo updmap-sys
```

and that's it. 
I spent hours on this problem, as I tried many solutions which didn't work and what worked is the above command. I am not a pro on LaTeX, just an intermediate user, so don't know many details, but here is what I understood:

what it does is read the `updmap.cfg` file and recreates the map files. So the files which you wanted to be created by below command:

```
updmap-sys --enable Map=xxx.map
```

are created!!

Comment: Welcome! This is not the best way. (See the discussion in comments on egreg's answer above.) However, it is not terrible, either - and infinitely better than the other answer here. Note, though, that it will not necessarily work since the user has installed in their home tree, I think, and whether it works or not will thus depend on how `sudo` is configured.

Answer (score 0):

For SuSE users: you should check the `TEXMFVAR` definition in `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.conf`. It probably points to the system wide directory defined in `TEXMFSYSVAR`. You should change it to `TEXMFHOME`:

```
TEXMFVAR = ${TEXMFHOME}
```

Then use `updmap` as a non-root user should do the job as advertised.

Comment: Sorry but this is absolutely terrible advice in part for just the reasons egreg explained in his comments above. **Do NOT do this.** If you can alter that configuration file, then you have root privileges, and **not** having such privileges is the **only** reason to use `updmap` in the first place. If you have to use `updmap`, it will be a pain. But, if you have no choice, you have to live with the pain. There is nothing special about SuSE. egreg's advice is good there, too.

Comment: @cfr What is special about (at least) SuSE is that if you follow the standard procedure it doesn't work. Before posting here, I had a mail exchange with Karl Berry on this, he said it _should_ work and, like you did, said that my suggestion should not be followed. However, instead of letting people get frustrated by things which should work but in fact don't, I prefer to show them where their pain comes from, even if they don't follow my suggestion. By the way, one reason for me to do it this way, is to preserve private fonts across system re-installations.

Comment: It is still terrible advice. In that case, there are 2 good options: (1) change distro or get your distro to package TL properly, or (2) install upstream TL rather than using your distro's packages (which is recommended anyway). As egreg explains in his answer, use of TEXMFHOME should be a last resort. I also maintain custom font installations across system re-installations. There is no problem with this. If neither (1) nor (2) is possible, option (3) is to not use locally installed fonts. A distant last option (4) is to use `TEXMFHOME` but you do not explain the other steps needed or issues.

Comment: @cfr There are no other steps needed and there are no issues.

Comment: Yet. There will be. That is the problem. If you want to do this yourself, that's up to you. But hopefully people will read these comments and not follow what remains terrible advice. Nobody denies that it will work.

Comment: Explanation of why you should **NOT** follow this advice can be found in my [question/answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i) on this.