# Why shouldn't I use getnonfreefonts to install additional fonts? Why shouldn't I use updmap when installing or removing fonts?

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing, scripts

This question and answer is a response to a request from Joseph Wright.

- Why shouldn't I use `getnonfreefonts` to install additional fonts?
- Why shouldn't I use `updmap` when installing or removing fonts?

---

### *Background*

There are a number of questions on the site concerning problems caused by people installing additional fonts and using `updmap` to update the 'map' files on which TeX depends.

One common cause of these problems is the use of `getnonfreefonts`.

Other causes are the use of other font installation scripts or executing `updmap` directly.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

## *What causes the problems?*

The essential problem here is that `updmap` is executed in some way, shape or form.

Running an older version of `getnonfreefonts` causes problems *because* it executes `updmap`.

Running `getnonfreefonts --user` causes problems *because* it executes `updmap`.

Other font installation scripts cause this problem *because* they execute `updmap`.
(Of course, not all scripts do this. But our concern here is with those which do.)

Finally, of course, executing `updmap` directly causes problems *because* it executes `updmap`.

## *What is the problem with `getnonfreefonts` [older versions] and `getnonfreefonts --user`?*

They run `updmap`. (See previous section if you are still unclear on this point.)

## *What is the problem with `updmap`?*

### *Short answer*

In essence, the problem is that `updmap` creates personal font mapping files which are not updated when fonts are removed, added or updated for the system-wide installation of TeX Live (e.g. when `tlmgr` is used to update).

### *Detailed explanation*

Tex Live provides a series of commands for managing a TeX installation. An especially important group of commands come in *two flavours*. These commands are named like this:

- `<command name>` and/or `<command name> --user`
- `<command name>-sys` and/or `<command name> --sys`

The command we are interested in, `updmap`, is one of these commands. That is, it comes in two flavours:

- `updmap`
- `updmap-sys`

This means that the first command manages configuration and installation *for the current user only*. The second command, `updmap-sys`, manages configuration and installation *for all users, system-wide*.

Both `updmap` and `updmap-sys` read a series of configuration files which tell them which `.map` files to look for and which to activate, as well as some information about how fonts should be used. They then try to read these `.map` files and use the information from them to create a number of 'super' `.map` files for various programmes to use.

Suppose, for example, that the programme finds a configuration file with the following lines

```
Map AnonymousPro.map
```

This tells it, among other things, to read the file `AnonymousPro.map` and enable the fonts that file describes.

For example, the first few lines of this file are

```
AnonymousPro-Regular-01 AnonymousPro <AnonymousPro-01.enc <AnonymousPro-Regular.pfb " fontinst-autoenc-AnonymousPro-01 ReEncodeFont "
AnonymousPro-Regular-02 AnonymousPro <AnonymousPro-02.enc <AnonymousPro-Regular.pfb " fontinst-autoenc-AnonymousPro-02 ReEncodeFont "
AnonymousPro-Regular-03 AnonymousPro <AnonymousPro-03.enc <AnonymousPro-Regular.pfb " fontinst-autoenc-AnonymousPro-03 ReEncodeFont "
```

which tells TeX, basically, what to do with requests for various fonts from the AnonymousPro family.

The crucial thing is that `updmap` or `updmap-sys` read this file and add the relevant information to the 'super' `.map` files they produce.

For example, they would add the following lines to `pdftex.map`, which pdfTeX uses in translating your request for AnonymousPro fonts into reality:

```
% AnonymousPro.map
AnonymousPro-Bold-01 AnonymousPro-Bold <AnonymousPro-01.enc <AnonymousPro-Bold.pfb " fontinst-autoenc-AnonymousPro-01 ReEncodeFont "
AnonymousPro-Bold-02 AnonymousPro-Bold <AnonymousPro-02.enc <AnonymousPro-Bold.pfb " fontinst-autoenc-AnonymousPro-02 ReEncodeFont "
AnonymousPro-Bold-03 AnonymousPro-Bold <AnonymousPro-03.enc <AnonymousPro-Bold.pfb " fontinst-autoenc-AnonymousPro-03 ReEncodeFont "
```

When you compile a document using pdfTeX or TeX, the small `.map` file fragment which is part of the package of AnonymousPro fonts is not read: TeX only reads the 'super' `.map` files which include information about all of the fonts available to the installation.

So far, both `updmap` and `updmap-sys` do the job.

But because `updmap` configures things only at the level of the individual user, it creates 'super' `.map` files in `TEXMFVAR`. On a typical GNU/Linux installation, this is `~/.texliveYYYY/texmf-var` where `YYYY` is the edition of TeX Live (e.g. `2017`).

The immediate results of this are great. The individual user finds everything works and newly installed fonts are suddenly available for use in documents.

But the files in `TEXMFVAR` now supersede the system-wide copies of `pdftex.map` and so on. Right now, that's OK because all of the system-wide information will be replicated in the new versions in `TEXMFVAR`.

The problems begin when the installation is updated. Let's suppose that the user now runs `tlmgr` to update the installation and is excited to see that a new type1 postscript font, GorgeousGraffiti, is installed. `tlmgr` does all the updating of everything, so it should be all ready to use. The user reads the documentation and tries to use the new font in a document.

TeX now complains that it cannot find the font. As it isn't sure what to do, it tries to find an `.mf` recipe to create a `.pk` file but, of course, there isn't one. Compilation fails.

Why?

When the user compiles with pdfTeX, the programme reads the 'super' `.map` files it uses. It gives priority to the ones in `TEXMFVAR` - not the system-wide ones. For example, it gives priority to the user's personal `pdftex.map` and doesn't read the system-wide one. (Similar things happen if the user uses TeX rather than pdfTeX.)

But `tlmgr` manages the system-wide configuration and installation. So it added the information about GorgeousGraffiti *not* to the individual user's copy of `pdftex.map` but, rather, to the system-wide copy in `TEXMFSYSVAR`. In order to get the information about GorgeousGraffiti added to the user's copy of `pdftex.map`, the user needs to run `updmap` again. And the same thing will happen every time `tlmgr` makes changes to the system font configuration - to integrate those changes in the user's copy of `pdftex.map`, the user needs to run `updmap` again.

This is, to put it mildly, a Pain.

***Running `updmap` even once means that the system-wide font map information will never be read again.***

In contrast, `updmap-sys` deals with the system-wide configuration. When you use `getnonfreefonts --sys` to install additional fonts, for example, the fonts are installed in `TEXMFLOCAL` and `updmap-sys` is used to add information about those fonts to the system-wide configuration.

When `tlmgr` is used to update the installation in this case, it will add the information about GorgeousGraffiti to the system-wide `pdftex.map` etc. as before. But this time, when the user compiles a document which uses that font, pdfTeX will not find any copy of `pdftex.map` in the user's personal `TEXMFVAR`. So, it will use the system-wide one from `TEXMFSYSVAR` instead. Since this version has been updated with the new information, pdfTeX will know all about GorgeousGraffiti and the document will compile successfully.

## *The moral of the story*

- Use `getnonfreefonts --sys` to install additional fonts.

  - Install `getnonfreefonts` in the usual way.
  - This will install a command, `getnonfreefonts`, with ***two*** flavours: `getnonfreefonts --user` and `getnonfreefonts --sys`. [Older installations may instead have `getnonfreefonts` for the user case and `getnonfreefonts-sys` in place of `getnonfreefonts --sys`. `getnonfreefonts --sys` should work in this case, too.]
  - When installing fonts in the collection, use `getnonfreefonts --sys`.
  - Although `getnonfreefonts --sys` and `getnonfreefonts --user` are the same basic command, the flavour you choose matters. If you call it by `getnonfreefonts --sys`, it will do The Right Thing. If you call it by `getnonfreefonts --user`, it will do The Wrong Thing.
  - Remember that Shakespeare was talking about roses - not font installation scripts: ***A font installation script by any other name does* NOT *smell as sweet.***
- If you use another font installation script, make sure it uses `updmap-sys`. Do ***not*** use a script which will run `updmap`.
- If you need to update the map files directly, always use `updmap-sys`.

## *If you read this too late*

Start by executing the following command to move the files generated by `updmap` out of the way. This only renames the directory. If all goes well, you can delete it later.

```
mv -n $(dirname $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFVAR)) $(dirname $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFVAR)).bkup
```

Note that running this command may cause slower compilation of some documents initially. For example, cache information will have to be regenerated by LuaTeX, `.pk` fonts will need to be recreated etc. It will be similar to first compilation after installing a new edition of TeX Live.

Note that `TEXMFVAR` only contains generated files. So everything here can be regenerated by TeX as required.

Now make sure that any fonts and associated files installed in `TEXMFHOME` are removed. If you aren't sure where that is, run `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME`. Do not delete the entire directory! If you have installed custom classes or packages, you want to keep those. You will need to check what should be removed and what not.

If you are sure you've not installed custom packages or classes into `TEXMFHOME`, you can try

```
mv -n $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME) $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME).bkup
```

Again, you can remove the directory later if you are sure you don't need anything in it.

Note that `TEXMFHOME` contains non-generated files. So if you delete essential stuff here, TeX cannot remake it for you!

When you are done, write the moral of the story on a note for yourself so you don't have to go through this again!

Comment: +1 A good question... and a good answer! No need for other participants! ;-)

Comment: You can't mean the sentence "Executing updmap directly causes problems because it executes updmap."? (paragraph 4)

Comment: @JimHefferon Oh, but I do! It was really just a way of emphasising the point. Possibly not the most eloquent way, but I think it does the job.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but there's something that is not clear to me yet: where do you get `getnonfreefonts-sys`? I mean, do you use the same installer [getnonfreefonts](https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) or do you have to do something completely different?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You use the same installer. Then, to install the fonts, you just use `getnonfreefonts-sys`. There's probably an option to `getnonfreefonts` which is equivalent.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I've edited the answer to try to make a bit clearer what is going on here, since I realised that the correct choice is a symbolic link to the incorrect one (on Unix-ish systems, anyway) and I figure this might just confuse things further. Whether my edit makes things better or worse is, of course, another question.

Comment: Dear @cfr, finding this page from Google, I notice there is no longer `getnonfreefonts-sys`, but shall be called as by `getnonfreefonts --sys`. See the [download page](https://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/)

Comment: @Aminopterin You still get `getnonfreefonts-sys`. It is just a link to `getnonfreefonts`, executed with the `--sys`. But you can say `getnonfreefonts --sys` if you prefer.

Comment: @Aminopterin That is, I downloaded it to check recently and the installation script hasn't changed from the 2015 version.

Comment: This is curious, because I just downloaded it and ran `getnonfreefonts-sys` (after unzipping I mean, see the link), but the error reads "command not found". But I ran `getnonfreefonts --sys` as indicated by the link, and installation seemed to be successful.

Comment: @Aminopterin The copy of the installation script I have includes the line `create_symlink (instdir) -- for getnonfreefonts-sys`. Does yours?

Comment: @Aminopterin OK. Yes, you're quite right, sorry. I checked the script still matched after I installed TL 2017 and it did, but either it has changed since or I somehow confused an old version for the new one. (I suspect it has changed, but I'm not 100% confident of this.) I'll update the instructions. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Aminopterin Please see edits above. Let me know if I've missed anything else :(.

Comment: You are welcome! If it were not for this post, I could not have installed garamond successfully, and I really like it (garamond). Btw, in 2017 I would advise people who want to use fancy fonts to use lualatex, as I think it (lualatex) has been mature enough. I haven't tried throughly though; I have still not found time to learn it beside my school work.