# Cannot change teletype font to beramono

Tags: fonts, packages, typewriter

I am trying to change the teletype font in my thesis document to Bera Mono. I downloaded the `beramono` CTAN package and unzipped it in my `~/texmf` folder (where I've already installed a few dozen packages).

Here is all of the preamble I have direct control over

```
% template .tex preamble
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{warwickthesis,setspace,graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

% my code starts here

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono} % this command breaks the \tt font on its own
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      % so does this

\usepackage{tikz}
```

Example of the problem:

`{\ttfamily Hi there} Hi there`:

[image: tt font compared to normal]

This is also how minted source code listings appear.

Instead of using Bera Mono, it seems to start rendering CM as a bitmap as the teletype font. I have tried a few other examples from the internet, *e.g.* courier, with the same effect.

Unless I've made a mistake in my package inclusion or ordering, I expect that the thesis template I'm using is causing the problem (I initially copied this out of a known working example using `courier`).

So, my question is: Have I made a mistake, and if not, is there a way I can absolutely *force* the use of the font?

---

#### Edit

Following Ulrike Fischer's advice, I minimised the packages and found the following telling error:

```
(/dcs/pg14/phulgm/texmf/tex/latex/bera/t1fvm.fd) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pd
ftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) ) </dcs/pg14/phulgm/.texlive2007/texmf-va
r/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm1095.600pk>kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+57/600 --dpi 657 fvmr8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for fvmr8r.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file fvmr8r): Font fvmr8r at 657 not found
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 2989 bytes).
```

[Full log](http://pastebin.com/s8LsV7u0)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Can you add the `\documentclass` line? Also `\{tt Hi there}` is wrong input.

Comment: Try `\ttfamily` instead of `\tt`

Comment: @egreg I've added the preamble that came with the template.

Comment: Sorry, but it's the same. You probably have installed wrongly Bera mono; just unzipping a font package is not sufficient. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @egreg I'm using probably some redhat distribution from eons ago - I'm on a university computer. pdfTeX using libpoppler 3.14159201.40.3-2.2. I've manually installed up-to-date versions of most packages to my `~/texmf` folder. I followed the instructions in the README: the first `bera.zip` contained a second `bera.zip` which it instructed me to unzip in my `tekmf` folder. I also moved the `.afm` files to `~/texmf/fonts/afm/public/bera` and the `.pfb` files to `~/texmf/fonts/type1/public/bera`. However, I did not take any steps beyond this - did I miss something?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have tried `\ttfamily` to no avail. I've updated my question to clarify that other environments which should automatically invoke teletype fonts (minted) suffer the same problem.

Comment: Was a fd-file in the zip and where did put it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `tex/latex/bera`. Six `.fd` files: `t1fv{e,m,s}` and `ts1fv{e,m,s}`

Comment: Comment all packages  in your preamble with the exception of beramono, fontenc and inputenc. Then try a small text with \ttfamily. If the font is wrong show the log-file.

Comment: What about `.tfm` files? The `.afm` files can't be used directly by TeX. Was there a `.map` file? Where did you put it? Did you run `updmap`? Note that running this is NOT generally recommended but, in this case, you have no choice.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've added the log to my answer - definitely looks meaningful, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @cfr there are plenty of `.tfm` files in `fonts/tfm/public/bera`. There are two `.map` files: `fonts/map/dvips/bera.map` and `dvips/config/bera.map`. I've never used `updmap`, but it seems to be being used: `[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]`

Comment: Run `updmap-sys --enable  Map=bera.map`

Comment: Yes, but that file won't have information about fonts installed by you for your own personal use. Try `updmap --enable Map=bera.map`. You should take a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i) so that you are aware of the issues which are associated with doing this, though.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The OP is on a university machine. I doubt they have rights allowing them to update the `.map` files for the entire university.

Comment: @cfr ah could be. well then updmap or `\pdfmapfile{=bera.map}` in the document.

Comment: Thanks everyone - running `updmap --enable Map=bera.map` solved the problem. "Luckily" for me, I don't think these computers are going to be updated any time soon.

Comment: @Qualia That's what I figured. But I thought you should know about the reasons not to do it in case you are tempted to do something similar on your own installation of TeX at some point ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install fonts into a TEXMF tree, TeX needs various things in order to use them:

1. The various files must end up in the directories TeX expects. In your case, this is already all in order.
2. TeX must be able to find the various files when it looks. Since you installed into your personal tree, `TEXMFHOME`, this is straightforward: TeX will find them so long as they are in the right places. (So if condition 1 is met, so is this one.)
3. TeX must know about the relationship between font names and fonts. For this, it uses a series of `.map` files (a different file for each method of compilation roughly). For example, for pdfTeX, `pdftex.map`. So these files need to include information about any new fonts. These files are managed by `updmap` or `updmap-sys`.

***In general, you should NOT run the following command.*** If you would like to know why - or if you have run the command already - please see [my question concerning this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i).

In the specific case of the OP, however, `updmap-sys` is not an option. Moreover, it is highly unlikely that the system-wide `.map` files will change at anything other than snails' pace. Hence, (1) the OP has no other option, and (2) this option will not, probably, have the side-effects which it typically does. At least, not very soon ;).

In this case, and given an understanding of the reasons for which this should NOT generally be done, the following command will add information about the new fonts to a custom copy of `pdftex.map`, enabling them to be used in documents.

Again, ***do NOT do this if you are not the OP and you are not in the OP's situation***. And ***do not do it without reading - and understanding - [my answer on this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255711/)***.

```
updmap --enable Map=bera.map
```

Alternatively, if the system-wide installation is being regularly updated, or if you don't want to use the font in many documents or whatever, you can add this to your preamble to add the `.map` on a document-by-document basis:

```
\pdfmapfile{+bera.map}
```

Note that the `+` *adds* the mappings from `bera.map` file to those pdfTeX gets from `pdftex.map` etc.