# Can newly installed texlive system link to a miktex's local texmf directory on same desktop?

Tags: fonts

I have an installed MiKTeX 2.9 system with a local texmf directory (purposefully for fonts). I would now like to install TeXLive 2015 on the same desktop. Can I configure the TeXLive system to use the same font directories?

Comment: Yes. but the other way round is easier: Move your files to the texmf-local or texmfhome of texlive and then add this texmf-tree to the miktex system.

Comment: Welcome! Move it to `texmf-local` (or `TEXMFLOCAL`, if different). Then you can use `updmap-sys` sensibly. (You can do this even if you use your personal tree, I think, but then things get icky and confusing.) See [my answer question/answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i).