# Font not found in map file (Minion Pro)

Tags: minionpro

I am trying to install the MinionPro package. I followed the instructions on CTAN and tried running the test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

I don't get any output, only an error message:

> name = MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa, rootname =
>   MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa, pointsize = mktexmf: empty or non-existent
>   rootfile!
>
> Cannot find font MinionPro-Regular-Base-aa in map file(s).

I'm at wit's end. Do you know what might be behind this error? Thanks!

Comment: What *exactly* did you do to install? Did you check that the fonts you used as the basis for conversion were the right version for the script you used? Did you get any errors or warnings? Which TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using TexLive 2015. I checked the version of Minion Pro using `otfinfo -v` to get the correct encoding (version 002.000).

Comment: After transforming into Type 1, I copied the fonts into my local directory, `C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\type1\adobe\MinionPro`. I copied the metrics and encoding zip files into the local directory and unzipped them through the command prompt. Then I ran `texhash`, `updmap-sys --enable Map=MinionPro.map` and `updmap-sys`. I got an error message in this last step stating that some files wouldn't be found because overriding files existed, but they don't seem related to Minion Pro (kanjix, pdftex, psfonts, etc.).

Comment: `.map` files? If you have a stale copy of `pdftex.map` which is found first, then the one you've added the fonts to won't be read. What `updmap-sys` does is create these `.map` files. TeX then uses them to find the fonts. `kpsewhich pdftex.map` will tell you where the one being used is. If that's not the one in `TEXMFLOCAL` and the one in `TEXMFLOCAL` is the one which knows about the new fonts, then the new fonts will not be found.

Comment: I ran `kpsewhich pdftex.map` and got `c:/Users/lucab/.texlive2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Oh, dear. You have either run `updmap` at some point or you've run `getnonfreefonts`. Hang on, I'll get you a reference.

Comment: See [my question and answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i) on this. Although the question is about *why*, the answer also explains what to do if the explanation reaches you too late. I assume you can adapt the command there for Windows. It is just a question of moving/deleting things. Basically, you need to remove `c:/Users/lucab/.texlive2015/texmf-var/`. Then it should work. If you have installed fonts into `TEXMFHOME`, best to install them in `TEXMFLOCAL` instead.

Comment: Deleting `C:/Users/lucab/.texlive2015/texmf-var/` did it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @cfr really thank you. I read that and your question an solution. First I had the same problem. Later, I noticed that I must use `updmap-sys` from MinionPro readme file. Then the problem was similar but with MinionPro-It ... anyway. I solve the problem following your question and solution. I have one question about install MinionPro package in TexLive2016 because the path for the step 4 in MinionPro readme file (Copy the generated Type1 fonts into your local TeX tree) is some different and that cause me dude.

Comment: @juanuni Glad it helped!