# installing (or using) the classico font

Tags: fonts

Using TexLive 2015 on OSX I have been having a problem with the classico font and possibly all fonts installed with 'getfreefonts'.

Using an earlier version of TexLive classico worked but when trying to use classico after upgrading to TexLive 2015 I have been getting error messages  such as:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file URWClassico-Regular-lf-ot1--base): Fo
nt URWClassico-Regular-lf-ot1--base at 480 not found

!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file URWClassico-Italic-lf-t1--base): Font URWClassico-Italic-lf-t1--base at 720 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Notably, file URWClassico-Italic-lf-t1 is in folder "/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/urw/classico"

I tried reinstalling all the fonts installed using 'getnonfreefonts -a -d -f'. That appears to download and install all the normal fonts installed via 'getnonfreefonts', but reports errors:

```
Running 'mktexlsr /Users/jeremyharbinson1/Library/texmf...              [done]

Updating map files (updmap). Be patient...updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /Users/jeremyharbinson1) to root's actual home (/var/root).
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:     classicovn.map (in /var/root/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]:     dayroman.map (in /var/root/Library/texlive/2015/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
```

etc.  - repeated for all the fonts it should have installed

If I run 'tex testfont' and choose 'classico' I get a message of which the essential part seems to be:

```
\testfont=classico not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found
```

I can find some classico related files (quite a few, in fact) in the texlive folder, so at least something is there, but presumably something important is missing (or there is something I need yet to do).

Comment: Never use `getnonfreefonts`. See [my question/answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i) for details. Your problem is almost certainly covered there.

Comment: Note that the script is creating a particular mess here as it seems to run some things with one setting of `HOME` and others with another. But the solution is the same regardless: delete the stuff it has created and use `getnonfreefonts-sys`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks - makes sense. I renamed the texlive installation to hide it and then re-installed it. That seemed a more certain option than deleting the files created by getnonfreefonts. And classico is working again. Jeremy

Comment: If you used `getnonfreefonts` to reinstall, then things will work now but break later. If you used `getnonfreefonts-sys`, that should work. But 'hiding' your TeX Live installation does not sound like a good solution. However, since I don't actually know what this means, perhaps it involved something more sensible than the description suggests.

Comment: As you suggested, I used getnonfreefonts-sys. By hiding I mean doing a dumb, brutal DOS-era thing. If something (eg Word.exe) in a path is causing a problem rename to xxword.exe to hide it, check it cannot be found anymore, then install new version (Word.exe) and see if works. This is crude, but it is easy, though I can see how on an more sophisticated os it might go wrong.

Comment: I more wasn't clear what you meant you'd hidden than how you'd hidden it. (Although hiding would normally probably mean put a dot before the name, but usually TeX Live uses a hidden directory, though perhaps not on Macs.) But if you renamed TeX Live in its entirety, you'd have to rename a bunch of stuff, including `/usr/local/texlive`. And that wouldn't actually help. It sounds like you probably renamed `~/.texliveYYYY` (or equivalent) which would, indeed, help. I think I say in my answer that renaming is an option. Though it's safe to delete if you are sure you're deleting the right thing.

Comment: As you suggested, I think texlive is not a dot file in OSX. I renamed that xxtexlive and all the symbolic links in texbin (I think that it is what it is called) got updated during the reinstall. I could not find any other directories that looked relevant - I hope I did not miss any.

Comment: You didn't need to touch `/usr/texbin` or `/usr/local/texlive` at all (although installing with `getnonfreefonts-sys` will affect `/usr/local/texlive`. The important stuff to get rid of is all in your home directory.