# Garamondx does not work for me anymore

Tags: fonts

I updated to MacTex 2015 from 2013 and I cannot use the garamondx font. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

And here is the error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+120/600 --dpi 720 zgmr8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for zgmr8r.
mktexpk: perhaps zgmr8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file zgmr8r): Font zgmr8r at 720 n
ot found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

However: I have installed getnonfreefonts, I have done

```
$ sudo getnonfreefonts -a
$ sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a
```

They're all updated and installed. So what's the problem? I have tried doing updmap, as I saw that in some other question, but it didn't work.

By the way, on my first run of getnonfreefonts -a, I got this:

```
Installing 'zgm.map'...updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /Users/myusername) to root's actual home (/var/root).
```

Same for all other fonts.

Comment: You should never run `getnonfreefonts` (as opposed to `getnonfreefonts-sys`) unless you are in an environment that doesn't let you superuser privileges. In any case `sudo` should not be prefixed to `getnonfreefonts`. Do an uninstall with `getnonfreefonts` and retry.

Comment: Writing `$ getnonfreefonts` gives `! ERROR: The install directory '/Users/myusername/Library/texmf is not writable.` Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, because you used `sudo getnonfreefonts` (which was wrong to begin with). Unfortunately, there's no uninstall option, so you have to do that manually.

Comment: No. That is not normal. It is a result of using `sudo getnonfreefonts`.

Comment: To do what manually? Set that directory to writable?

Comment: Please see [my question and answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i) on this for details. It includes information about what to do if you have already done what you shouldn't as you have. You need to remove the fonts you've installed using `getnonfreefonts`, correct permissions on any remaining directories and then make sure you have the current version of the scripts installed and make sure `getnonfreefonts-sys` has installed **garamondx** correctly.

Comment: @cfr: Thanks. I've done what you say, but now running `getnonfreefonts-sys` issues `! ERROR: The install directory '/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local' is not writable.` Oh, I hadn't seen your edit. Should I manually correct permissions on this folder?

Comment: @cfr: Ok, I dealt with that, I reran getnonfreefonts-sys, but at the end of it I get `Updating map files (updmap-sys). Be patient...updmap: Directory "/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap" isn't writable:  at /Library/TeX/texbin/updmap line 1406.
                         [failed]` Thank you for any help.

Comment: Well, whatever, since I had just installed MacTeX, I just uninstalled it and installed it again. Now, using `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys`, it worked ok.

Comment: You should use `sudo` with `getnonfreefonts-sys` if you've installed MacTeX because it writes in directories which are owned, by default, by `root`. You shouldn't use `sudo` if you use `getnonfreefonts` because it writes to directories which should be owned by you. However, since you shouldn't use this script at all, this is largely beside the point. I'm glad you got it sorted. You should check ownership and permissions on TEXMFHOME etc., though if you deleted the stuff there as suggested in my answer, probably it is mostly OK.