# Trouble installing Letter Gothic font

Tags: fonts, installing, typewriter

I am unable to install the Letter Gothic font. I downloaded the lettergothic.zip file from the ctan website. The readme file instructed me to copy some files to certain places, which I did. However, when I try to compile my document, I get the following error message: ulgothic.sty not found. I understand this because there was never any explicit .sty file that I downloaded. I am unable to find ulgothic.sty anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is you distribution?

Comment: There is a ulgothic.sty in ulg.zip. http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/lettergothic

Comment: Hi. I use MacTeX.

Comment: Remove the files you installed manually and then use `getnonfreefonts-sys` to install URW's LetterGothic. (You can install the other fonts available, too, if you wish, although you don't have to.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URW's LetterGothic can be installed using the `getnonfreefonts` scripts.

1. Download the scripts from [here](https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/).
2. Follow the instructions to unzip the archive and install the script using `texlua`.
3. Use `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys` to install the fonts on your system.

**Important: do NOT use `getnonfreefonts`. ONLY use `getnonfreefonts-sys`.**

The installation provides both scripts. It is crucial to choose the `-sys` version in order to avoid later problems. For an explanation of this, see [my question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i) on this topic.

Once the font is installed, you can load the `ulgothic` package. However, you must also switch to the T1 font encoding as the package neither supports the default encoding, OT1, nor activates the T1 encoding automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{ulgothic}
\begin{document}
\texttt{URW's Letter Gothic}
\end{document}
```

[image: URW LetterGothic]

Comment: The command texlua install-getnonfreefonts is not able to create a new directory. I get the following error message:
Julius:desktop julius$ texlua install-getnonfreefonts
Detected System: x86_64-darwin
Detected Installation: /usr/local/texlive/2015
mkdir /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/scripts/getnonfreefonts ...   [failed]
Sorry, couldn't create directory /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/scripts/getnonfreefonts
Julius:desktop julius$

Comment: @Julius Did you use `sudo`?

Comment: Oops. My bad. Novice mistake. Sorry about that. :) I managed to install all the fonts. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. My instructions here aren't very specific in part because it can depend on how you've set things up (and whether `sudo` even exists on your OS).