# Installing getnonfreefonts MacTeX

Tags: fonts

I am getting the same error as Julius (see link and error below). But I'm a newbie and don't understand how to use `sudo` as @cfr suggests in the comments.

[Trouble installing Letter Gothic font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309157/trouble-installing-letter-gothic-font)

```
Jeremys-MacBook-Pro:documents jeremy$ texlua install-getnonfreefonts
Detected System: x86_64-darwin
Detected Installation: /usr/local/texlive/2017
mkdir /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/getnonfreefonts ...   [failed]
Sorry, couldn't create directory /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/getnonfreefonts
```

Comment: you put `sudo` before the command you wish to execute. you will be prompted for your admin password and than the command will be executed. I.e.: `sudo texlua install-getnonfreefonts`