# Font ua1r8r at 624 not found

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive, font-encodings

my thesis was built successfully on texbasic2015. Today I updated my textlive version to [texbasic2016](https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html). After updating and installing all required packages, it is not possible to build the thesis. In fact, it throws the following error:

```
{/usr/local/texlive/2016basic/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc} </Users
/macbookpro/Library/texlive/2016basic/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ect
t1200.600pk>
!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ua1r8r): Font ua1r8r at 624 n
ot found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I tried googling a lot and still couldn't find a solution. Could you please help?

UPDATE: When I start building, it shows the following alerts:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, `getnonfreefonts` doesn't write its `updmap.cfg` in `texmf-local`. Did you use `getnonfreefonts-sys` to install `uarial`?

Comment: @egreg I don't know. I've downloaded and installed getnonfreefonts from https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html

Comment: @egreg Oh, I think I've install uarial already. When I run command "getnonfreefonts --lsfonts", it shows arial-urw installed

Comment: I had to run `getnonfreefonts-sys -r`, then the map files were included. You could also try `\pdfmapfile{=ua1.map}` in your document.

Comment: The command `getnonfreefonts-sys -r` does nothing for me but the second command does work. I wish I can upvote 1000 times for you. Thank you for saving my days.

Comment: Please read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i. It is a question and answer I wrote to explain why you should not use `getnonfreefonts` but only `getnonfreefonts-sys`. This is partially off-topic because you'd like run into this problem even if you'd used `getnonfreefonts-sys` for the reason egreg gave, but you would at least avoid similar related problems.

Comment: In this case, start by following the instructions in my answer to undo the use of `getnonfreefonts` (and `updmap`, if applicable). Then use `getnonfreefonts-sys` to install the additional fonts you would like. This should get you back to a working installation and put you in better shape to avoid the problems I describe in the link.