# AGU journal template: missing font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, linux

I'm currently looking into the AGU journal style (download class and example [here](http://publications.agu.org/files/2016/08/agu-template-updated-20160806.zip)). When I try to compile the example .tex file using pdftex (v. 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14) and Texmaker on Linux Mint, I get the following error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file rntxbmi): Font rntxbmi at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

However, when I do `ls ~/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/newtx | grep rntxbmi` it returns `rntxbmi.tfm` to me, indicating that the font does exist. I have seen countless questions such as these on the interwebs, but none of the offered solutions seem to work (for instance, I've tried all sorts of combinations of `updmap` and `updmap-sys` commands).

I have very little experience fixing problems like these, so it would be greatly appreciated if any of you could give me a hand.

Comment: The .cls file defaults to `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`. It seems they're not installed on your system. Install the  `newtx` package – and may be `tex-gyre`, which contains TeX Gyre Termes, a times-clone used by `newtx`, unless it's already installed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `newtx` is installed using `tlmgr`, and I found the `rntxbmi.tfm` file inside one of the `newtx` directories (see original question)

Comment: It is really problematic to install fonts into your personal TEXMF tree. You should use your distro's package manager rather than `tlmgr` and install the relevant packages. If you do this, then you will also need to undo the effects of `updmap`. If decide not to, you need to use `updmap` to update the mapping files and you need to do this every time Linux Mint updates TeX Live packages which include fonts. (That is, in addition to updating your system, each time you will need to check if you need to re-run `updmap`.)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i for information about the world of pain you invite by installing fonts into your personal TEXMF tree. Note that the TFM is not sufficient on its own. Depending on the font, you must also have PFB or MF and, possibly, VF files, in addition to the LaTeX support and map fragments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have now tried to install the possibly culprit package `newtx` using the system's package manager (it appears in `texlive-fonts-extra`), but it fails stating `updmap-sys` failed, since it cannot find `rntxbmi.map (in /root/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)`. It seems I got myself in a position where I cannot move either forward or backward anymore. I also tried to undo the works of `updmap` following your instructions, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I fixed the problem, or at least cured the symptoms. In the end, I went to `/root/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` and removed the line `Map rntxbmi.map`. I did the same for my local `.texmf-config` directory. After that, I was able to run `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` and run `updmap-sys` as a root, and `updmap` as a local user. This is probably not the right way of solving it, but at least I can now compile my pdfs (including the example given in the original question). Please comment if you foresee any potential trouble caused by this method.