# mathfrak not working

Tags: amsmath, texlive, linux, amssymb, linuxfedora

I'm using Fedora 24 and I can't get to work the `mathfrak` command. I keep getting this error message:

```
pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file eufm10): Font eufm10 at 600 not found
```

I'm not able to find the package I should install in order to make it work. How can I fix this?

A minimal (non)working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

$$\mathfrak{k}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Offtopic, but have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: the font requested seems to be a bitmap font.  there are type 1 fonts for `eufm10` in the tex live distribution (`.pfb`, `.pfm` and `.afm` to be precise).  check in the fonts area of the tex live distribution tree -- look in `fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/euler` for the first two.  if they are present, then the problem is probably a deficiency in the `map` file that controls what font files are being looked for.

Comment: @barbarabeeton and where is this tree directory?

Comment: i really don't know where it is located on a fedora installation.  but if you enter `kpsewhich eufm10.tfm` (because we *know* a `.tfm` file was found), that should show you the root of the tree.

Comment: Try `\pdfmapfile{=euler.map}`.

Comment: Also the order in the first line is wrong, class options go in front of the class specification

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That solves the problem! Could you add this as an answer and maybe explain why is it happening? It could be good also if there is a way to permanently fix this (I mean without including `\pdfmapfile{=euler.map}` on each pdf?)

Comment: What exactly did you install on fedora? Latex is often broken up into many smaller pieces when you get it from a Linux distribution, so getting the right components is very confusing (which is why I often recommend getting the upstream texlive instead, yes it takes a lot of space 4-5Gb, and you'll never use 90%,but it just works as intended)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've cheked that ans I have a lot fonts there, in particular I have `eufm10.pfb` and `eufm10.pfm`. How can I fix the 'problem' with the `map` file?

Comment: Normally you should be able to enable the map permantly with `updmap-sys --enable Map=euler.map` but it is possible that you messed up the maps and that is doesn't work.

Comment: Definitely it is messed up :( I've tried `updmap-sys --enable Map=euler.map` and it doesn't work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well I've tried `updmap --enable Map=euler.map` without root permissions and now it's working! Thanks. I have no idea why the maps are wrong. It's a common problem in the setting we have here (we are several students with the same config of brand new Fedora boxes, all with the same problem).

Comment: Well when you once called updmap instead of updmaps-sys you will have to do it after every installation of fonts as this is one of the ways to mess up the map-file.

Comment: @xndrme What Ulrike said is correct; you should get rid of the `pdftex.map` created by running `updmap` and always run `updmap-sys` (if ever).

Comment: @egreg How do I get rid of `pdftex.map`? Where is this file? By the way the system was messed up before I ran `updmap`... any idea why?

Comment: @xndrme Run “`kpsewhich pdftex.map`” (no quotes) and the system will tell you; it should be under `~/texmf` or similar place. Rename the file to something else, so the TeX programs won't find it. The main tree `pdftex.map` will be used.

Comment: @xndrme Please read my question/answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i. This explains why you should not use `updmap` and what to do if you already did. The map file you need to remove is almost certainly under `~/.texliveYYYY` where `YYYY` is a year e.g. `2016` or `2015`. If you ran `kpsewhich`, however, it will have given you the correct place. However, this should mean you need the additional line back in your `.tex` as the original problem is unresolved.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, I've wiped out the wrong map. But it is working fine now (maybe because I did the `updmap-sys`). In any case it would be good to have a solution, this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: You should wipe out the right map unless you plan to remember to run `updmap` every single time fonts are updated in your installation of TeX Live. It will work fine now. That's expected. It will break later. That is also expected. Please read the link I provided for an explanation of why and how it will break. Running `updmap-sys` without deleting the correct `.map` file is entirely pointless and will have no effect. Indeed, that is precisely the problem.

Comment: You should report the problem to your Linux distro. If installing the relevant package doesn't update the `.map` files correctly, there is a problem with the scripts run by their package and it needs to be corrected there. If you used upstream's installer, the problem would lie in TeX Live. (But you would be much less likely to experience a problem using upstream's installation.)