# How to get Type1 Lucida fonts in pdflatex output?

Tags: fonts, texlive, ubuntu, lucida

Many years ago I bought the Lucida fonts from TUG, and I've been always struggling to get them working as I changed OS and TeX distributions... Now I'm with Ubuntu 12.04, and the bundled TeX Live (i.e., installed through the Ubuntu package manager).

I got at least to the point where pdflatex does not stop due to missing fonts. I have the lucida files in `~/texmf`, then I ran:

```
updmap --enable Map=lucida.map
update-updmap
updmap
```

(not sure this was the right way, but that's what I did). And now the following test file compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[expert]{lucidabr}

\begin{document}
Test $x^2$

\sffamily Test
\end{document}
```

But I get bitmapped CM fonts instead of vector Lucida (except for the math x):

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       4  0
BIMIZZ+LucidaNewMath-AltItalic       Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       5  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no       6  0
```

What am I missing? What's the best way to diagnose it and fix it?

As far as can see, I do have Type1 Lucida fonts available:

```
$ ls ~/texmf/fonts/type1/bh/lucida/
lbc.pfb   lbd.pfm    lbi.pfb   lbkr.pfm   lbma.pfb   lbmdo.pfm  lbmi.pfb  lbmr.pfm   lbmstex.pfm  lbsl.pfb   lbtb.pfm  lfdi.pfb  lfi.pfm   lsb.pfb   lsd.pfm  lstbo.pfb  lsto.pfm
lbc.pfm   lbdsc.pfb  lbi.pfm   lbl.pfb    lbma.pfm   lbmd.pfb   lbmi.pfm  lbmsd.pfb  lbr.pfb      lbsl.pfm   lbto.pfb  lfdi.pfm  lfr.pfb   lsb.pfm   lsi.pfb  lstbo.pfm  lstr.pfb
lbdi.pfb  lbdsc.pfm  lbki.pfb  lbl.pfm    lbmdi.pfb  lbmd.pfm   lbmo.pfb  lbmsd.pfm  lbr.pfm      lbtbo.pfb  lbto.pfm  lfd.pfb   lfr.pfm   lsdi.pfb  lsi.pfm  lstb.pfb   lstr.pfm
lbdi.pfm  lbh.pfb    lbki.pfm  lbmad.pfb  lbmdi.pfm  lbme.pfb   lbmo.pfm  lbms.pfb   lbrsc.pfb    lbtbo.pfm  lbtr.pfb  lfd.pfm   lsbi.pfb  lsdi.pfm  lsr.pfb  lstb.pfm
lbd.pfb   lbh.pfm    lbkr.pfb  lbmad.pfm  lbmdo.pfb  lbme.pfm   lbmr.pfb  lbms.pfm   lbrsc.pfm    lbtb.pfb   lbtr.pfm  lfi.pfb   lsbi.pfm  lsd.pfb   lsr.pfm  lsto.pfb
```

ETA:

This is in the `.log` file:

```
(/home/jellby/texmf/tex/latex/lucidabr/lmrhlcm.fd
File: lmrhlcm.fd 2005/11/28 v4.3 Lucida New Math Arrows (SPQR/DPC/TUG)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+hlh on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file T1hlh.fd. on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/hlh/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+hlcm on input line 7.

[...]

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+hls on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file T1hls.fd. on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/hls/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 9.
 [1

{/home/jellby/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
 )
```

Comment: Never run `updmap`!  Always use `updmap-sys` as root.  This howevers requires that your fonts are installed in a system location rather than your home directory.

Comment: @HenriMenke I figured I'd rather run things as a normal user until I know what I'm doing. What's wrong with ``updmap``?  It must be possible to have the fonts in the user directory too, since I had it working before (it was Ubuntu 10.04, I believe).

Comment: Why you shouldn’t use `updmap` (or any program that runs `updmap`): http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255711/10995

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for that. Since I'm the only user in the computer, I don't use ``tlmgr``, and I'm OK running ``updmap`` whenever I update font/map files, I don't think I'm in big trouble.

Answer (score 3):

I found the missing `t1hlh.fd`, `t1hls.fd` files, along with others, in a `~/texmf/tex/latex/lucida` (not `lucidabr`) in another computer. I have no idea where they came from (now I do, see below), but copying this directory over to the new computer worked:

```
$ pdffonts test.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZHPZPA+LucidaBright                  Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
BIMIZZ+LucidaNewMath-AltItalic       Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       5  0
YRCRIT+LucidaSans                    Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       6  0
```

ETA:

These `.fd` files came with the fonts. I found the original `lucida-complete.zip` file, and it contains both `lucidabr` and `lucida` directories inside `$TEXMF/tex/latex`. So it was all my fault, for not copying this initially (thinking it might have belonged to another package).