# LinLibertineT font not found but available in filesystem

Tags: fonts, errors, pdftex, libertine

The following minimal *not*-working example (mnwe) gives me an issue with the used libertine font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
  \section{Hello World}
  Lorem ipsum, ...
\end{document}
```

When building with `pdflatex`, I get the following error:

```
pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base): Font LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base at 600 not found
Check the TeX log file for more information
```

The `missfont.log` file contains the following:

```
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 LinLibertineT-tlf-t1--base
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base
```

And the TeX log:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty
Package: libertine 2014/11/25 (Bob Tennent) Supports Libertine and Biolinum fon
ts for all LaTeX engines.


(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/LinLibertine_I.tex)) (./mwe.aux)
\openout1 = `mwe.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 3.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+LinuxLibertineT-TLF on
 input line 3.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/OT1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd
File: OT1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd 2012/11/26 (autoinst) Font definitions for OT1/
LinuxLibertineT-TLF.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 3.
\c@mv@tabular=\count88
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count89
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 14.4pt on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/b/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 14.4pt on input line 4.
 [1

{/home/user/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./mwe.aux)
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2013 strings out of 493013
 34424 string characters out of 6139316
 70831 words of memory out of 5000000
 5586 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 8253 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,4n,33p,172b,109s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base): Font LinLibertineT-
tlf-ot1--base at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I have `texlive 2016.42515-2` installed on ArchLinux with kernel `4.8.13-1-ARCH`. I tried to manually locate the missing font and was able to find it:

```
 0 ✓ user@alcor ~ $ find /usr/share/texmf-dist/ | grep -i "LinLibertineT\-tlf\-ot1\-\-base"
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base.tfm
```

Now I am wondering why `pdflatex` does not recognize that font?

Comment: It seems that generating the fonts on the fly failed. Try to execute the commands in `missfont.log` by hand. Does this work? Maybe `mktexpk` cannot be executed, or some directory is not writable. Do you have a texmf tree in your home directory, where the fonts can be written?

Comment: libertine is a type1 font. It shouldn't try to create a pk. If this happens it normally indicates that something is wrong with the map-file. Does it work when you add `\pdfmapfile{=libertine.map}` to your document?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer this works. What's the magic behind that?

Comment: Your map-file is not correct and so I'm adding it manually. You seem to have a user pdftex.map (`/home/user/.texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map`)  which means that updmap-sys no longer works. See here for an explanation: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. The linked question is a very good resource. Running `updmap` _twice_ again somehow fixed the `pdftex.map` missing entries. Now it works. You are a wizard!