# The oldstyle figures of garamondx don't work

Tags: fonts, garamondx

I can't compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\useosf

\begin{document}
1234567890
\end{document}
```

(Well, Emacs actually says it has `successfully compiled 0 pages`. He's optimist.)
I've just upgraded both `texlive` and the typefaces. Does it compile for you?

Comment: the emacs message isn't so useful, what does the tex log for that document look like? `garamondx` isn't in texlive so I don't have it installed for example.

Comment: I get oldstyle figures

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes sorry, I forgot to add it. It says `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file zgmosfnums.enc): cannot open encoding file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: I updated the fonts through `getnonfreefonts` yesterday, since I saw there was an update available for `garamondx`. Can it be the cause? I didn't try that package before, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: I can't test now, but imho there are two possible error causes: the new font setup has an error (a missing file or a faulty map entry) or everything is correct but you need to run updmap-sys or updmap (depending on your system, don't run updmap unless you understand the consequence) to update your local map files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've read the manual and I haven't seen any dangerous consequence in running `updmap`. Can you explain or give a link?

Comment: I think I've found one. [Why shouldn't I use getnonfreefonts to install additional fonts? Why shouldn't I use updmap when installing or removing fonts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to duplicate installation of the software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault, I installed the updates with `getnonfreefonts` instead of `getnonfreefonts-sys`. When I installed TL2016 I followed [cfr's advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/187379#187379) and created a dedicated user and home. I don't know whether it had any influence on this issue.

In order to solve this problem I had to remove the files created by `getnonfreefonts` (the non`-sys` version; see [Why shouldn't I use getnonfreefonts to install additional fonts? Why shouldn't I use updmap when installing or removing fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i)) and run `getnonfreefonts-sys -a`.

[Edit] I also had to run `getnonfreefonts-sys -r` to get all typefaces to work properly after that.

Many thanks to Ulrike Fischer who lighted my `PATH` to the solution.