# TrueType Font fatal error

Tags: truetype

I am trying to use the `tolkienfonts` package.

I followed what was written in the package documentation for installing it, but I cannot make it work. This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}                       

\usepackage{tolkienfonts}
\pdfmapfile{+tolkien.map}

\begin{document}
\Quenya{Test.}
\end{document}
```

which gets one fatal error and several warnings.

The warnings are all similar to

```
pdfTeX warning: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file /Users/username/Library/texmf/fonts/map/
tolkien.map): fontmap entry for `TengwarA' already exists, duplicates ignored
```

but with a different name (e.g. TengwarAA, TengwarAAi, TengwarAAb and so on). If I remove the line `\pdfmapfile{+tolkien.map}`, they disappear. However, it was written in the package documentation to add this line, which is confusing.

**Question 1**: Why this happens and how can it be solved?

The second question regards the single fatal error

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file tngan.ttf): cannot open TrueType font
 file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

**Question 2**: How can I resolve this?

Note that this fatal error happens even if I remove the line `\pdfmapfile{+tolkien.map}`.

I wrote two questions just to be more explicit and highlight some aspects, but they are not really different, as they are related to the same fundamental issue: how can I make this package work?

P.S. I use TeXShop, version 3.89.

Comment: TeXShop has notthing to so with this, this is a LaTeX matter, not an editor matter. Did you manually install the fonts? Where? Did you update the filename database afterwards?

Comment: Ok, one question at a time. The package came with some fonts already in it. Outside of the package, I installed only the _Tengwar Eldamar_ font and the _Tengwar Eldamar Alt_ font simply by double clicking on it, which opened the OS X app for fonts. I left the files themselves where I downloaded them. I don't understand your last question.

Comment: The answer to your last question is probably "no".

Comment: If you installed the font into Mac OS X, then pdflatex cannot find. It only knows fonts from within the LaTeX installations. You'd probably need to use xelatex or lualatex in order to use Mac OS X system installed fonts.

Comment: By compiling with LuaLaTeX, I get the following error: `!LuaTeX error: cannot find TrueType font file for reading (tngan.ttf).`

It appears this 'tngan.ttf' isn't between the package files nor the font I installed.

Comment: lualatex not just use fonts as you do with pdflatex. You need to use `fontspec`, which can be very confusing. It might be easier to simply fonts you need to use and place them in the dir of your doc, and then try with pdflatex again.

Comment: Sorry but I can't follow you clearly, this is getting very complicated. Can you write an answer with a step-by-step procedure? The file `tngan.ttf` is freely available online, if you need it.

Comment: I solved it, but please post an answer so I can upvote you.

Comment: Just do a self answer, I don't know which steps you did. Might be quite useful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used is based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i), which clearly explains why you should never use `updmap` or similar shenanigans. The package documentation of `tolkienfonts` suggests to use that, but you must undo this passage (as explained in the answer), since it creates all sorts of unwanted behaviours.

The solution is, instead, as follows.

- **Step 0**: Assume that your folder with LaTeX files is called `tolkientest`
- **Step 1**: Download the `tngwar.ttf` file and install it by double click
- **Step 2**: Move the `tngwar.ttf` file in the folder `tolkientest`
- **Step 3**: Add `\usepackage{tolkienfonts}` and `\pdfmapfile{+tolkien.map}` in the preamble
- **Step 4**: Compile with LaTeX as usual.

Clearly, this is a solution only for the specific file `tngwar.ttf`. As the package documentation is silent on the actual names of the files that you need to download (it only generically says you need to download *Tengwar* fonts, without explicitly giving you the specific name `tngwar.ttf`, which is the real thing you need), it may arise the need to repeat this procedure when a new font is needed.