# EB Garamond (bold) small caps "suddenly" unavailable in lualatex?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, linux, small-caps

Since I could come up with an MWE for the problem, I'm completely rewriting this post - if curious about my original problem, check [this past revision (1)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/404517/1).

Consider this MWE, `test.tex`:

```latex
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}

% compile with: lualatex test.tex

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

  \makeatletter
  \newcommand{\name}[1]{\def\@name{#1}}
  \makeatother

  \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
  \geometry{left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \newfontfamily\titlenamefont{EB Garamond}[Ligatures=TeX]
  \usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

  \name{\hspace{4em}\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=10.0}\textsc{Brazen Discovery}}

  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
      {\ifcsname titlenamefont\endcsname\titlenamefont\fi \Huge\bfseries{\@name}\par}
    \makeatother
  \endgroup\medskip

  Testing some normal paragraph text here...

\end{document}
```

I have an **old** machine, which has some hardware broken, but can still be used under some circumstances, with Ubuntu 14.04 and TexLive 2014 or 2015 (I've always used TexLive by installing it in an "off" folder, and then adding `/path/to/texlive/2014/bin/i386-linux` to the `$PATH`).

Then, I have a **new** machine, with Ubuntu 14.04 installed from scratch, and TexLive 2014 or 2015 copied from the old machine verbatim (but still at the same path). The compilation process runs OK on both machines, but there is a problem with the fonts.

The **old** machine reports this:

```
$ uname -a
Linux myOldPC 4.4.0-57-generic #78~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Dec 10 00:16:09 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
$ echo $(lsb_release -i -d -r -c)
Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Release: 14.04 Codename: trusty
$ tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 39298 (2016-01-07 03:44:29 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /path/to/texlive/2014
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2014
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)
```

When I build with `lualatex test.tex`, the output finishes with:

```
$ lualatex test.tex
...
(/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.c
fg)) (/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.
sty)) (./test.out) (./test.out) [1{~/.texlive2015/texmf-var/fo
nts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux))
 301 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 attribute, 44 glue_spec, 3 attribute_list
, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:42,3:4,4:38,5:22,6:65,7:2,8:2,9:13,10:5
</path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-re
gular.otf><~/.fonts/EBGaramond08-Regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 8339 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

The PDF document looks like this in `evince`:

[image: test_old.png]

... basically, the title font is sort of bolded, and in small caps - and the fonts embedded in the PDF are:

```
$ pdffonts test.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
IJJDUA+EBGaramond08-Regular          CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      8  0
QXSXVQ+LMRoman10-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      9  0
```

... that is, `EBGaramond08-Regular` is included for the title (which corresponds to the `<~/.fonts/EBGaramond08-Regular.otf>` in the last lines of the `lualatex` log).

The **new** machine reports this:

```
$ uname -a
Linux myNewPC 4.4.0-101-generic #124~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 10 19:06:11 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
$ echo $(lsb_release -i -d -r -c)
Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Release: 14.04 Codename: trusty
$ tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 39298 (2016-01-07 03:44:29 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /path/to/texlive/2014
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2014
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)
```

So, pretty much everything is the same, except for the kernel version. When I build with `lualatex test.tex`, the output finishes with:

```
$ lualatex test.tex
...
(/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.c
fg)) (/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.
sty)) (./test.out) (./test.out)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/EBGaramond(0)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU2/EBGaramond(0)/m/n' instead on input line 23.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/EBGaramond(1)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU2/EBGaramond(1)/m/n' instead on input line 23.



LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU2/EBGaramond(1)/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `EU2/EBGaramond(1)/bx/n' instead on input line 23.

[1{/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

)
 310 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 1 kern, 4 attribute, 44 glue_spec, 4 attrib
ute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:40,3:4,4:37,5:22,6:65,7:2,8:2,9:13,10:5
</path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-re
gular.otf><~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 7527 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

So, besides the difference of `310 words of node memory` (vs `301 words of node memory` in the case of old pc), there are also undefined font shapes - which, in the case of `bx/sc`, I guess it means that the bold small caps shape is undefined.

The PDF document looks like this in `evince`:

[image: test_new.png]

... basically, the title font is sort *not* bolded, and *not* small caps - and the fonts embedded in the PDF are:

```
$ pdffonts test.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
JYJWKP+EBGaramond12-Regular          CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      8  0
QXSXVQ+LMRoman10-Regular             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      9  0
```

... that is, `EBGaramond12-Regular` is included for the title (which corresponds to the `<~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf>` in the last lines of the `lualatex` log) - but, it does *not* correspond to the `EBGaramond08-Regular` used in the build on the old machine ?!

So, I guess my questions are:

- How come, that more-less the same `lualatex` on the same OS environment, can pick one font family in one case (old PC build), and another in another case (new PC build), for the exactly same `.tex` source file?
- How can I get the build on the new machine, to perform the same and generate the same document, as the build on old machine?

Note that both old and new machine report this:

```
$ luaotfload-tool --find="EB Garamond"
luaotfload | resolve : Font "EB Garamond" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf"
```

If I look up the garamond OTF fonts on both systems and compare them, I get:

```
# $ find / -xdev -iname '*garamond*.otf' 2>/dev/null | sort | tee findold # on old PC
# $ find / -xdev -iname '*garamond*.otf' 2>/dev/null | sort | tee findnew # on new PC
$ diff -U 100000 findold findnew
--- findold 2017-12-05 07:13:18.813205949 +0100
+++ findnew 2017-12-05 07:13:09.413124141 +0100
@@ -1,15 +1,11 @@
 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond08-Italic.otf
 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond08-Regular.otf
 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf
 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-Italic.otf
 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf
 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond-InitialsF1.otf
 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond-InitialsF2.otf
 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond-Initials.otf
 ~/.fonts/EBGaramondSC08-Regular.otf
 ~/.fonts/EBGaramondSC12-Regular.otf
-~/.fonts/GaramondNo8-Italic.otf
-~/.fonts/GaramondNo8-Medium-Italic.otf
-~/.fonts/GaramondNo8-Medium.otf
-~/.fonts/GaramondNo8-Regular.otf
```

... so at least I have the same EBGaramond filenames (GaramondNo8 is, I guess, "URW Garamond", not EBGaramond). Turns out, I also have the exact same `EBGaramond*.otf` files too (apparently, from [EBGaramond-0.016.zip](https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads/EBGaramond-0.016.zip) - see past revision for code how I got it installed on new PC):

```
# $ find / -xdev -iname '*ebgaramond*.otf' 2>/dev/null | sort | xargs ls -la | sed "s/$(whoami) $(whoami)//" | tee ls-laold # on old PC
$ find / -xdev -iname '*ebgaramond*.otf' 2>/dev/null | sort | xargs ls -la | sed "s/$(whoami) $(whoami)//" | tee ls-lanew # on new PC
-rw-r--r-- 1  200656 Apr  8  2014 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond08-Italic.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1  259968 Apr  8  2014 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond08-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1  212492 Apr  8  2014 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1  298252 Apr  8  2014 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-Italic.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1  495300 Apr  8  2014 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1   60240 Apr  8  2014 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond-InitialsF1.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1    5120 Apr  8  2014 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond-InitialsF2.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1   78512 Apr  8  2014 ~/.fonts/EBGaramond-Initials.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1  226840 Apr  8  2014 ~/.fonts/EBGaramondSC08-Regular.otf
-rw-r--r-- 1  353364 Apr  8  2014 ~/.fonts/EBGaramondSC12-Regular.otf
$ diff -U 100000 --report-identical-files ls-laold ls-lanew
Files ls-laold and ls-lanew are identical
```

Relevant entries in luatex-cache names also are identical on both old and new PC:

```
$ zgrep -i ebgaramond /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.lua.gz | grep -v '"full"' | grep fullpath | sort
   ["fullpath"]="~/.fonts/EBGaramond08-Italic.otf",
   ["fullpath"]="~/.fonts/EBGaramond08-Regular.otf",
   ["fullpath"]="~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-AllSC.otf",
   ["fullpath"]="~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-Italic.otf",
   ["fullpath"]="~/.fonts/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf",
   ["fullpath"]="~/.fonts/EBGaramond-InitialsF1.otf",
   ["fullpath"]="~/.fonts/EBGaramond-InitialsF2.otf",
   ["fullpath"]="~/.fonts/EBGaramond-Initials.otf",
   ["fullpath"]="~/.fonts/EBGaramondSC08-Regular.otf",
   ["fullpath"]="~/.fonts/EBGaramondSC12-Regular.otf",
```

... and the only difference seems to be in luatex-cache otf fonts:

```
# $ ls -la /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond* | sed "s/$(whoami) $(whoami)//" | tee luatex-cache-otf-old # on old PC
# $ ls -la /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond* | sed "s/$(whoami) $(whoami)//" | tee luatex-cache-otf-new # on new PC
$ diff -U 100000 luatex-cache-otf-old luatex-cache-otf-new
--- luatex-cache-otf-old    2017-12-05 07:48:06.679082205 +0100
+++ luatex-cache-otf-new    2017-12-05 07:45:15.625596626 +0100
@@ -1,6 +1,4 @@
--rw-rw-rw- 1  473749 Oct 28  2016 /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond08-regular.lua
--rw-rw-rw- 1  303043 Oct 28  2016 /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond08-regular.luc
--rw-rw-rw- 1  568196 Oct 28  2016 /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond12-italic.lua
--rw-rw-rw- 1  364914 Oct 28  2016 /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond12-italic.luc
--rw-rw-rw- 1  724218 Oct 28  2016 /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond12-regular.lua
--rw-rw-rw- 1  466820 Oct 28  2016 /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond12-regular.luc
+-rw-rw-rw- 1  568148 Dec  4 16:21 /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond12-italic.lua
+-rw-rw-rw- 1  364894 Dec  4 16:21 /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond12-italic.luc
+-rw-rw-rw- 1  724173 Dec  4 16:21 /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond12-regular.lua
+-rw-rw-rw- 1  466728 Dec  4 16:21 /path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/ebgaramond12-regular.luc
```

I tried diffing, say, `ebgaramond12-italic.lua` on old and new machine -  but there is simply way too many changes, that are changes of numbers in numeric references (as in `["slookups"]={ 983214, 983316, 983112, 983418 },`), so that doesn't reveal much.

Besides that, the only obvious difference is that on the *new* machine, `ebgaramond08-regular.lua`/`.luc` fail to get generated in `texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/` (and they should get generated if they don't exist upon first next run of `lualatex`) ... AND, from the `lualatex` log:

- **old** machine uses `~/.texlive2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` (it also has `texmf-config` in `~/.texlive2015`)
- **new** machine does not have `~/.texlive2015`, and it so uses `/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` (apparently?)

  - though, if I run `updmap` on new machine, `~/.texlive2015/texmf-var` gets created (but `~/.texlive2015/texmf-config` does not), and then `lualatex` reads the `pdftex.map` in it - but the same problem with the fonts persists..

I'm really at loss with how to proceed debugging from here ...

Comment: Be aware that the TeX-distributed EBGaramond might not contain all of the fonts! Have a look at the package vis ctan.org, and also have a look at the designer's own web site: http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/

Comment: Thanks @RobtAll - in my final step, I do use the author's zip, but I still cannot get the bold smallcaps to work...

Comment: This problem is easy to show in a minimal document. You need only to try to use the font in a small size and \scshape.

Comment: There is no bold in the EB Garamond family.  At one time, the CTAN package provided an unsatisfactory bold, but that was removed at the request of the font designer.

Comment: You could try to force the issue with something like `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[BoldFont=EBGaramond08-Regular]`, but that’s a crime against good taste, and Garamond will be turning in his grave.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer - I managed to get to the old machine, and demonstrate the problem with an MWE, so now the OP is completely changed; please take a look.

Comment: Thanks @Thérèse - I will try to stay away from crimes against good taste, haha `:)` I have completely changed the post with an MWE now, and I guess the real question is: how can two systems, with nearly identical OS, TexLive and (relevant) font installations, have a different compilation process (and PDF results) - and how to make it identical again?

Comment: Never run `updmap` if you can possibly avoid it. If you cannot avoid it, think twice before running `updmap`. Usually it is easier to change your mind about what you want to do than to deal with the consequences of using this command. If you ever do or ever have run `updmap`, make sure that you understand the consequences and are prepared to deal with them when (not if) you run into mysterious troubles.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i for details, advice and remedial action.

Comment: Why are you still using 2015 or 2014 rather than 2017? LuaTeX is not beta any longer ;).

Comment: Thanks @cfr for the link, good to know - why I use an older version: I tend to stay on older versions because more often then not, I experience "update bugs" exactly when I don't have time to deal with them `:)` So I usually wait when I have enough time to upgrade everything, both OS and programs. In this case, I had moved to a new PC, needed to build this document quickly, knew it did build fine on the old PC install (the texlive 2014/15), and thought it would be quickest to just copy that install over (which as shown, basically works, but with caveats).

Comment: With TeX or pdfTeX, it would be different. But you're using LuaTeX, so it isn't going to work like that and it really doesn't 'basically work' - you're essentially launching a space rocket with key components held together using sellotape ....

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I solved this somewhat, but it's all kind of patchy - so if anyone knows how I could "repair" this install (but without reinstalling from scratch), I'd love to hear it.

The thing is: while on the old machine, I did install TexLive 2014 / 2015 at the time using the `install-tl` script (but in an "off" folder, that is to say, folder in a non-system, additionally mounted partition); on the new machine, I simply copied the installation from the old machine's "off" folder to the new machine's "off" folder (i.e. additionally mounted partition, with the same path(name) as the "off" folder on the old machine). (I'm a big fan of running software from externally mounted partitions, with minimal interventions in what would be considered the OS install tree).

I had assumed, that since both (old and new) "off" folders have the same path, all I need to do is add the same `/path/to/texlive/2014/bin/i386-linux` to the `$PATH` in `.bashrc`, and things would work the same - and generally they do (i.e. the executables run as usual). Except, I had forgotten there are additional folders created in `$HOME` (apparently created by `install-tl` or `tlmgr`, although I cannot recall if I created any of them manually).

So, after making sure, as in the OP, that I have the same fonts placed in the new machine at the same location as in the old one, I repeated the copying, this time with the `$HOME` folders:

```bash
rsync -aP oldPC.lan:/path/to/texlive /path/to/
rsync -aP oldPC.lan:~/.texlive2014 ~/
rsync -aP oldPC.lan:~/.texlive2015 ~/
rsync -aP oldPC.lan:~/texmf ~/
```

After this copy, finally the `test.tex` as in OP compiled fine, no complaints about undefined font shapes, and the PDF looks the same as the "old" PC example in OP.

I guess, one could say that if the same font files are in the same location at the "new" PC as in the "old" PC (i.e. where the texlive install/luatex-cache would expect them to be, as shown via `fc-list`), and if the texlive installation is at the same path at the "new" PC as in the "old" PC, - then with the above folder copy, the cached information from the "old" PC will be applicable to the "new" one as well, and Latex compilation will execute in the same manner.

Except, not quite. Before I get to that, note that this command started showing the same output on "new" machine as on "old" only after the above `rsync` copy:

```
$ kpsewhich --all updmap.cfg
~/.texlive2015/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/path/to/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg
/path/to/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

Before the copy, the line `~/.texlive2015/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` was not output. As noted in OP, `updmap` on new machine creates `~/.texlive2015/texmf-var` even if `~/.texlive2015` didn't previously exist; but then, what creates `~/.texlive2015/texmf-config` ? In this case, I had just copied `~/.texlive2015/texmf-config` from the "old" machine to the "new", and because the paths are the same, things happen to work - but I guess it would be more proper to generate `~/.texlive2015/texmf-config` using some tool (like `~/.texlive2015/texmf-var` is generated by `updmap`; I had hoped there's a `tlmgr --repair` for something like this, but no, there isn't. There is `tlmgr check all`, but it reports the same error on both "old" and "new" machine).

Possibly because of this, I experienced another font issue: after the copy, and confirming that `test.tex` works, I returned to the original document that caused this trouble, and couldn't compile it because the font Lato was not found. So I copied the Lato files to where luatex-cache would have expected them (in this case, in `~/.fonts/` on "new" machine), and ran:

```bash
luaotfload-tool -vvv --update --force
```

... but after this, the Lato fonts were found - but EB Garamond reverted back to the same error as in the OP! So, after this, I had to re-run the `rsync` copy process again to "undo" the effects of `luaotfload-tool` (and the only thing the copy process replaced were `lato*` and `ebgaramond*` files in luatex-cache) - and then finally compilation completed as on the "old" machine.

Well, it would be great to know how to restore or repair the copied install on "new" machine, so also the `luaotfload-tool` call results with working compilation process - but I guess, my usage case is already way too obscure, for that to be a straightforward answer...

Comment: Check to see if any of the files or folders are actually links to somewhere else.

Comment: `/usr/local` is designed for non-system, locally-installed software, by the way. It is its raison d'être. Neither `tl-install` nor `tlmgr` touch your home directory (unless you tell them to). However, normal compilation will create directories such as `~/.texliveYYYY`. So, unfortunately, with `updmap` (which you should never use).

Comment: When you rerun `luaotfload`, it deletes the current cache and creates it anew. Since you don't have the same fonts installed on this machine - the same ***system*** fonts - the result will correctly omit fonts you don't have. It seems likely that `fontconfig` is looking in different places or you don't have the same fonts at all or some other muddle is taking place. In general, your 'solution' is extremely fragile and will break. If you installed from upstream, did you configure `fontconfig` to use fonts from the TeX tree? If not, the fonts in your TeX install are mostly irrelevant.