# Installing enpassant fonts

Tags: chess, xskak, chessboard, chessfss

I would like to use the Merida chess font. However, I'm not familiar with Latex fonts and their installation. I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 and TexLive. After reading the readme file for https://ctan.org/pkg/enpassant?lang=de, I did the following:

1. copying the files to usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/*, where * ist the folder as suggested in the readme. I put the .map file to fonts/map/divps/chess/enpassant, as the readme didn't specify an exact location.
2. creating chess-merida-board-fig-raw files using ttf2pt1 as suggested by the readme file and putting them to the folders as described in step 1.
3. running `mktexlsr` and `sudo updmap -sys --enable Map=enpassant.map`, although I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing there :-)
4. adding
   `\setchessboard{boardfontfamily=merida}`
   to my .tex file to get the following error after running `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode pgn2latexGER.tex`
   :

   > kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi
   >   600 chess-merida-lsb mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for
   >   chess-merida-lsb. mktexpk: perhaps chess-merida-lsb is missing from
   >   the map file. kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to
   >   missfont.log. (see the transcript file for additional information)
   >   !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file chess-merida-lsb): Font chess-merida-lsb
   >   at 600 n ot found  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file
   >   produced!

Is there any easier way to install the Merida chess font or how would I do that properly?

Comment: The name of the map-files is `chess-enpassant.map` not enpassant.map. Add \pdfmapfile{=chess-enpassant.map} to your document as test. If it then compiles the installation is correct and you can repeat the `updmap-sys` step to enable the map globally.  And sorry but as texlive doesn't contain the package and the fonts can not be put on ctan the installation can not be easier.

Comment: Thank you, adding `\pdfmapfile{=chess-enpassant.map}` to the documents works :-) . However, `sudo updmap -sys --enable Map=chess-enpassant.map` doesn't seem to work, because without setting the pdfmapfile the document keeps crashing.

Comment: Here's the output: updmap[WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /home/fkern) to root's actual home (/root).
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.

Comment: There is no space after updmap, updmap-sys is one word.

Comment: mmh, both produces the same output and the problem persists. Still, I can live with the \pdfmapfile{=chess-enpassant.map} solution :-)

Comment: Probably you messed up the system wide map files and the user map files. See this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i