# pdflatex, installing a font, working on one machine, not on the other

Tags: fonts, installing, pdfpages

I have two MacBooks, one for work, one for myself, both running the up to date OS and MacTeX 2018. On one machine (it's half a year older and had MacTeX2017 before, but I only did the following with MacTeX2018), I unpacked the font (sadly it's a not that official package of my university using

```
sudo unzip tucroboto.zip -d $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL)
```

updated the database

```
sudo -H mktexlsr
```

and installed the maps

```
sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map=rob.map
sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map=robc.map
sudo -H updmap-sys --enable Map=robs.map
```

and tested the font

```
pdftex testfont
```

(using `robcl8t`, then `\table`, then `\bye`) and it happily produced a pdf.

Now I got the second machine two weeks ago and wanted to do the same today; I ran the same commands, and as far as I remember, the output is the same (the line `Scanning for Map entries         [275 files]` gladly increases for all three calls and there is no error), however, trying to do the test with pdflatex yields

```
!pdfTeX error: pdftex (file robcl8r): Font robcl8r at 600 not found
```

And I am looking into everything and searched for differences that might happen, but I can't see any difference, neither between the machines, nor the installations and why the same commands do not yield the same result.
Why do I get that error message and how can I solve that? What am I doing wrong/different here?

Comment: the error means that the map files have not been updated correctly. The reason is quite often that sometime in the past you run updmap (without the sys) and no have user map files. So check which pdftex.map pdftex is using and which one updmap-sys is updating.

Comment: That sounds interesting, especially because `updmap` and `updmap-sys` sound so similar. Thanks for the tip, how can I check for that?

Comment: Check the log file on the nonworking system and report the path of `pdftex.map`, please.

Comment: …Or, equivalently, type `kpsewhich pdftex.map` at the Terminal prompt and report what the reply is.

Comment: I don't know exactely how that happened, maybe even by accident (either reading `updmap -sys` or just mistyping – but that was the reason and interestingly I didn't find that by googling. The `kpsewhich`tip helped faster, thanks to you two anyways. You all three made my evening.

Comment: If one of you could explain what the difference of those two commands is and why one of them “breaks” font installation for quite a while until you delete one `pdftex.map` I would gladly except that as an answer :)

Comment: Ulrikes comment refers to the updmap manpage, you'll get it with `texdoc updmap` in a terminal / console / cmd...

Comment: See, for example, [Why shouldn't I use getnonfreefonts to install additional fonts? Why shouldn't I use updmap when installing or removing fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255709/69818)

Comment: This is explained in the Q&A @GuM linked. Would it make sense, do you think, to close this as a duplicate? It isn't really a duplicate question, so it really shouldn't be marked as such. But that is probably the most useful Q&A for this topic and anyone with the same problem. (Disclaimer: I wrote that Q&A. In my defence, I wrote it because we didn't have anything explaining it and nothing else has come along that I'm aware of.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the question, @cfr. I think your post answeres my question (because I used `updmap`, which you shouldn't). My problem was probably, that searching did'n't bring me to your post (and that I used `updmap`, which you shouldn't. Maybe you could answer this question with “The problem with `updmap` is answered here (linking to your post) – then it's not a duplicate but solves this question with an answer? Because you're right, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps @UlrikeFischer would like to answer along those lines, since her comment solved the problem?