# Baskervaldx swash shape not working

Tags: fonts, ligatures

I am trying to use the latest [`Baskervaldx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/baskervaldx) package (2020-Nov-07; included in TeXLive2020) with the `swash` feature either as a package option or using the `\swshape` command. I use `latexmk -pdf` to compile my document, but the following error appears:

```
...
kpathsea: Running mktextfm Baskervaldx-Ita-tlf-swash-t1
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation B for Baskervaldx-Ita-tlf-swash-t1.
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input Baskervaldx-Ita-tlf-swash-t1
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded base=mf)
...
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: Baskervaldx-Ita-tlf-swash-t1.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input Baskervaldx-Ita-tlf-swash-t1' failed to make Baskervaldx-Ita-tlf-swash-t1.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/Baskervaldx-TLF/m/sw/10=Baskervaldx-Ita-tlf-swash-t1 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
...
```

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\swshape

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Any idea what is missing? The only Baskervaldx files that have 'swash' in the filename in my TeXLive distribution under `/usr/local/texlive` are e.g. `Baskervaldx-Ita-tlf-swash-t1.htf` but I have no idea what `mktextfm`, `.htf` etc. are. I tried to load `\usepackage[T1,LY1]{fontenc}` or use xelatex `latexmk -pdfxe` but these didn't work either with the same errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some (unknown) reason, the swash fonts have been dropped, see http://tug.org/svn/texlive?limit_changes=0&view=revision&revision=56883 I can only think to a mistake, because the ChangeLog doesn't report the dropping and the documentation still mention the fonts. Report to the maintainer.

Comment: @egreg I see, just relieved it's not me doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else with the same problem, the package maintainer has been notified and said corrections should appear soon.

Comment: Michael Sharpe is always very kind and quick in fixing problems. You can make a self-answer when the issue is solved, so the thread can help people who find in the same situation.

Comment: @egreg Will do. While Googling I have found out there are so many packages he's contributed, rather amazed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a self-answer. The maintainer of the package was notified of the missing font files and he kindly and promptly updated the package.

I used `sudo tlmgr update baskervaldx` to install the update.

[Caveat: `tlmgr` was complaining my local version was 2017 and thus an older release (2017 < 2020). This wasn't the case as I only recently installed TeXLive 2020. I then found out I had to 'sudo su' it, since the distribution is under `/usr/local/texlive/`. But then the `$PATH` environmental variable stored in my `~/.bashrc` is apparently not used in root mode, so I had to manually and explicitly export $PATH in my terminal again.]

I then did `sudo texhash` and `sudo updmap-sys` to refresh everything.

[Caveat: Initially I got the error message `mktexpk: perhaps Baskervaldx-Ita-tosf-swash-t1--base is missing from the map file.` even though `Baskervaldx-Ita-tosf-swash-t1--base.tfm` etc. could be found under my distribution after the update. I then came across this post, [Why shouldn't I use getnonfreefonts to install additional fonts? Why shouldn't I use updmap when installing or removing fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i?nor), and did `mv -n $(dirname $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFVAR)) $(dirname $(kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFVAR)).bkup` (near the bottom of the top answer to the linked post). After that pdfTeX compiled fine.

As a last resort, XeLaTeX with package fontspec would always work and was working before.