# Fonts not found

Tags: kpathsea

As I told in a previous question, I'm migrating from Scientific Linux 6.2 to Slackware Linux 15.0.
I anticipated some problems but there are some I'm unable to solve myself.

My present question concerns some fonts TeX cannot find.
The first are omega fonts for greek letters: `omsegr`, `omsegri`, `omsegrb`, `omsegrbi`.
All fonts are present in the required directories: 
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/omega/omsegr.pfb
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/misc/omsegr.tfm
and
/usr/share/texmf-dist/ls -R
contains reference to those files in
./fonts/type1/public/omega
and
./fonts/tfm/public/misc
Moreover
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/fonts/map/dvips/omega/omega.map
contains
omsegr OmegaSerifGreek <omsegr.pfb 
and so on.

However `kpathsea` does not find the required files and outputs a message about a missing map file.
What is happening?

EDIT

I follow Ulrike'suggestion.
Here is a minimum file showing the problem.

```
\font\gbold=omsegrb
{\gbold a} + {\gbold b}
\bye
```

Log file

```
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2021 on Slackware) (preloaded format=tex)
(./baremin.tex [1] )
Output written on baremin.dvi (1 page, 264 bytes).
Transcript written on baremin.log.
```

When running `xdvi baremin` I get

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 omsegrb
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for omsegrb.
mktexpk: perhaps omsegrb is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
xdvi: Can't find pixel font omsegrb; using cmr10 instead at 600 dpi.
```

The `missfont.log`

```
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 omsegrb
```

Comment: show a small but complete example and also the exact error message, not your interpretation.

Comment: A very warm welcome!

Comment: I am using Xubuntu 22.04, MikTeX distribution and TeXStudio on my laptop. So far, I didn't run into `path` issues. My installation is user based, meaning most of my TeX files are inside my `home` map. Did you read chapter 5 of the `Kpathsea` manual? Could it be a search path issue in the configuration of TeXLive on Slackware? Slackware is a rather minimalist distribution, that requires more Linux knowledge than Xubuntu.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited my post to follow your suggestion. Hope this suffices.

Comment: what happens if you do  `dvips baremin`  and `pdftex baremin`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Same error messages frorn mktexpk.

Comment: good, it is easier to debug pdftex than xdvi (which I don't have). Run some example with pdftex that doesn't error, and check at the end of the log which pdftex.map pdftex is using. Then run `updmap-sys --listmaps` and check (at the begin of the messages) if it updates your pdftex.map, and also check if it uses the map file from your font. (The most typical source for faulty maps are that you used updmap-user once, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255711/2388).

Comment: The fact that the font is listed in `omega.map` is irrelevant if it is not also in `psfonts.map`. Running `updmap-sys` might fix the issue.

Comment: @egreg updmap-sys with which arguments?

Comment: @ElioFabri I guess with `--enable omega.map`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I ran pdftex with an error-free tex file (peri.tex). In peri.log I read "/usr/share/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map". That map file is not named in listmaps message, nor can I find "omega.map".

Comment: where is the pdftex.map that `updmap-sys` actually creates?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can find no pdftex.map file. In /usr/share/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/ there is a symlink to pdftex_dl14.map but it is dated feb 7 2022.

Comment: updmap-sys tells you at the begin which files it writes and where (at least it does in on windows ...).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, he says  he will read /usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg and he may write /usr/share/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg. But this file does not exist, as well as pdftex.map

Comment: show the complete output of updmap-sys

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's too long for a comment. You find it in http://www.sagredo.eu/temp/updmap.msg

Comment: well you could edit your question. But obviously it is much less verbose than on windows. Try if you find an option that says more.