# xdvi does not find ps2pk.map

Tags: texlive

I'm working in a texlive2012 distro, under Scientific Linux 6.2 (like Red-Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2).
When executing xdvi on a TeX file otherwise good, I get the following message:

"Could not load any of the map files listed in xdvi.cfg - disabling T1lib"

Actually in xdvi.cfg just one map file is named: ps2pk.map
It is present in several paths: kpsewhich found it in
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/pxdvi/ps2pk.map
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map
/root/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map

I executed sudo mktexlsr and sudo texhash but nothing changed.

EDIT:
I forgot to say that it's a novel bug, never appeared in the past 10 years.

Comment: So what changed in the system between the time that it worked and the moment that it stopped working? Did you do any updates, modified configuration settings, installed additional fonts, etc., within the TeX Live environment or elsewhere in the system? Presumably those changes are responsible for the current issue.

Comment: @Marijn Quite sure! You may glimpse at my previous post and comments [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672840/fonts-not-found]. Of course I'm not aware of how and when I did the damage. Now I need a diagnosis for the present situation. Apparently only xdvi suffered: tex, dvips, pdftex ... all work properly.

Comment: are you really using a texlive from 2012? so more than 10 years old? in your previous question you claimed that you have texlive 2021.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have both and are migrating from the old Linux to the new one. When I write a post, I expect that whoever answers has read my post with some care. Should l change my attitude?

Comment: well I doubt that will find someone who can debug a migration from a texlive 2012. Why don't you drop all this old stuff and install a new, sane system?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My present question does not concern migration, but a problem with my old texlive 2012. Please stand by that question, if you like.

Comment: ah, sorry I misunderstood. Well I also have some doubts that you will find someone who can debug a old xdvi on an old linux from that data you gave. It is e.g. quite unclear if the map is not found or faulty. Did you try if absolute pathes in the cfg work? Did you check the dates of the map-files? Was one of them changed recently?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK, now you gave me something to check and try. Thank you. This is precisely what I needed: what could I check? which files to examine? I don't believe the age should be an obstacle: how many changes, and where, were made to texlive in ten years?

Comment: I'm on windows and I have no idea how xdvi works. So I can only say: Play the detective and look around for clues. Regarding changes here is a list of the texlive changes starting with 2012: https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-800009.1.9 (this doesn't include changes in formats and packages). 2013 for example mentions "xdvi: now uses FreeType instead of t1lib for rendering.".