# Is there any reference to write a package from otf files?

Tags: packages, otftotfm

I have created some otf files of fonts for symbols and I'd like to write a package from them and then upload it to CTAN. But I have no experience in writing a package. So is there any reference to write a package from otf files? Please give some advice on the references which should be very basic. Specifically, with otf files of some fonts for symbols in hand, how to write a package like [`MnSymbol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol)?

Comment: What do you mean? If you're using LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX, you can use `fontspec` to use any OTF without needing any additional package. If you're using pdfLaTeX/LaTeX, you can't use such fonts as is regardless of any packages available. Are you converting them with `otftotfm` as your tag suggests?

Comment: Note that, if you are installing fonts with `otftotfm`, I strongly advise NOT using the `-a` option. It installs the fonts at the user level, which creates all kinds of problems. To avoid problems, let the tool create the files in the current directory and then install them and update the map files systemwide.

Comment: @cfr I revised the statements.

Comment: Which engine do you want to use them with? Do you want to use them in maths or text? `otftotfm` suggests (1) pdfTeX (or, possibly, TeX) and (2) text. Are the symbols arbitrary (e.g. ornament-like) or do they have e.g. unicode or TeX names?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i?r=SearchResults&s=231%7C3.7254 (on the updmap installation issue). But this doesn't apply if you're installing it as a system font for use with Lua/XeLaTeX or if you use MikTeX.

Comment: Have a look at package `libertinus-fonts`, which contains nothing but fonts. No *sty file. Then have a look at related packages `libertinus` and `libertinus-otf` which contain LaTeX program code for using those files. Not needing code support, I use `libertinus-fonts` as-is.